# How do I setup DiffMerge with msysgit / gitk?

Tags: git, windows-xp, msysgit, diffmerge

I've just started using Git and it's possible I've missed something obvious, but here goes:

- I'm using msysgit 1.6.2.2 on Windows XP
- While installing, I picked option 1 to "Use Git Bash only"

I'm trying to put together a wrapper script that I can use to replace the built in git diff with DiffMerge. Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-visual-diff-program) on SO, I created the following batch file:

```
@echo off
REM ---- Switch forward slashes to back slashes ----
set oldW=%2
set oldW=%oldW:/=\%
set newW=%5
set newW=%newW:/=\%

REM ---- Launch DiffMerge ----
"C:/Programs/SourceGear/DiffMerge/DiffMerge.exe" /title1="Old Version" %oldW% /title2="New Version" %newW%
```

I placed the bat file under %GIT_INSTALL%/cmd and edited my .gitconfig file as follows:

```
[diff]
external = C:/Programs/git/cmd/git-diff-wrapper.bat
```

If i launch Git Bash and execute
    git diff HEAD HEAD~ -- myfile

I get a message `File (\dev\null) not found` - which given I'm on Windows is not surprising.

Pressing on, I launched gitk and under Edit>Preferences, I chose the same wrapper script. Trying the "external diff" option for a particular file gives the cryptic error message `Unknown Option "`

Clearly, I have no idea what I'm doing anymore so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just completed my answer with some "DiffMerge" specific elements, as requested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just experienced a somewhat similar experience with [setting Notepad++ as my external editor with msysgit1.6.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows/773973#773973).

The key was to realize the wrapper was not a DOS script, but a /bin/sh script.

So try to put in your ".bat" (even though it is not exactly a bat script, the extension is not important here):

```
#!/bin/sh

# diff is called by git with 7 parameters:
# path old-file old-hex old-mode new-file new-hex new-mode

"C:/Programs/SourceGear/DiffMerge/DiffMerge.exe" /title1="Old Version" "$2" /title2="New Version" "$5" | cat
```

Do not worry about making all the '`\`' go '`/`': it is done by the Git scripts calling the external diff tool.

I did not test it with DiffMerge, but with WinMerge, it works just fine, both from a DOS session or a Git Shell.

```
#!/bin/sh
"C:/Program Files/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe" -e -ub "$2" "$5" | cat
```

(with the '`-e`' option, I have just ot type on '`ESC`' to close and quit the diff tool: that works great!)

---

[image][average_geek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94756/averagegeek) adds in the comments:

> added the '`/bin/sh`' header and tried running git diff again.
>   This time the error is:
>   `Unexpected parameter 'C:/Docume~/avggeek/LOCALS~1/Temp/.diff_b08444`
>   Is there a way to see what are the parameters getting passed when I call `git diff` ?

1/ There actually is a way to see what are the parameters getting passed!
Add the following line in the `C:\Program Files\Git\libexec\git-core\git-sh-setup` file:

```
git_editor() {
    : "${GIT_EDITOR:=$(git config core.editor)}"
    : "${GIT_EDITOR:=${VISUAL:-${EDITOR}}}"
    case "$GIT_EDITOR,$TERM" in
    ,dumb)
        echo >&2 "No editor specified in GIT_EDITOR, core.editor, VISUAL,"
        echo >&2 "or EDITOR. Tried to fall back to vi but terminal is dumb."
        echo >&2 "Please set one of these variables to an appropriate"
        echo >&2 "editor or run $0 with options that will not cause an"
        echo >&2 "editor to be invoked (e.g., -m or -F for git-commit)."
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
#### ADD THIS LINE BELOW
    echo >&2 "editor is ${GIT_EDITOR:=vi} $@."
#### END ADDITION ABOVE
    eval "${GIT_EDITOR:=vi}" '"$@"'
}
```

You will see what editor is being called, with what parameter.

Now, regarding the "Unexpected parameter" part:
I did have the same kind of error when I called WinMergeU.exe with "`/e /ub`" instead of "`-e -ub`", so first question is:
Are you sure that the "`/title1`" bit could not be used as "`-title1`" or "`-t1`" or  "`--title1`" or "`--t1`" ? That is what Is can see from the [chapter 9 "Command Lines Arguments" of the pdf documentation of DiffMerge](http://download-us.sourcegear.com/DiffMerge/3.3.0/Linux/Ubuntu/DiffMergeManual.pdf).
If not, I suspect some double quotes are in order for delimiting properly the different parameters. Something like:

```
"/title1="Old Version"" "$2" "/title2="New Version"" "$5"
or
"/title1=\"Old Version\"" "$2" "/title2=\"New Version\"" "$5"
```

But my money would rather be on the "`-title1`" or "`-t1`" form:

```
-t1="Old Version" "$2" -t2="New Version" "$5"
```

should work just fine.

Comment: I added the `/bin/sh` header and tried running git diff again. This time the error is:
    Unexpected parameter 'C:/Docume~`/avggeek/LOCALS~1/Temp/.diff_b08444

Is there a way to see what are the parameters getting passed when I call `git diff`?

Comment: "The key was to realize the wrapper was not a DOS script, but a /bin/sh script." For those like me not activating the "Use Git Bash only" option, it must be a Windows script (.cmd is more fashionable...) Same as your but using %2 instead of $2

Answer (score 15):

I looked all over the internet for the answer to this. I tried all of the solutions above and elsewhere. I could get the merge part to work and not the diff part or vice versa. So what I did eventually was to hack together my own **simple solution** from all the info I got on the internet which works for me. 
It does not require any scripts only that you edit your `.gitconfig` which normally resides in the following directory `C:\Documents and Settings\[username]` You'll need to have DiffMerge program installed already.

Here is relevant extract of my `.gitconfig` file. You'll just need to edit the path to where your version of of `DiffMerge` is. **Note** that I used the old DOS 8.3 format in the path

```
[diff]
    tool = diffm
[difftool "diffm"]
    cmd = "H:/PROGRA~1/SourceGear/DiffMerge/DiffMerge.exe $LOCAL $REMOTE"
    prompt = false

[merge]
    tool = diffmerge
[mergetool "diffmerge"]
    cmd = "H:/PROGRA~1/SourceGear/DiffMerge/DiffMerge.exe --merge --result=$MERGED $LOCAL $BASE $REMOTE" 
    trustExitCode = false
    keepBackup = false
```

You can also set it up using the commands `git config --replace --global [options]` if you so wish.

---

This simple solution works perfectly for me, too. For more recent versions of DiffMerge (3.3.1), the command path needs to be changed:

```
    cmd = "C:/PROGRA~1/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe ...etc..."
```

Comment: Props for a simple solution that just makes sense.

Comment: Like @Bnjmn said, +1 for simple solution that only requires editing .gitconfig

Comment: The key for me was changing `... /merge /replace=...` to `... --merge --replace=...`; [SourceGear's docs](https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/webhelp/sec__git__windows__msysgit.html) seem to be wrong.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me with as follows:

In `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[merge]
tool = diffmerge
[mergetool "diffmerge"]
cmd = \"C:/Program Files/git/cmd/git-diffmerge-merge.sh\" \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$MERGED\"
trustExitCode = false
```

In `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git-diffmerge-merge.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

localPath="$2"
basePath="$1"
remotePath="$3"
resultPath="$4"

if [ ! -f $basePath ]
then
    basePath="~/diffmerge-empty"
fi

"C:/Program Files/SourceGear/DiffMerge/DiffMerge.exe" --merge --result="$resultPath" "$localPath" "$basePath" "$remotePath" --title1="Mine" --title2="Merged: $4" --title3="Theirs"
```

Part of the credit goes to http://therightstuff.de/2009/01/28/Setting-Up-SourceGear-DiffMerge-With-Git.aspx ;)

Answer (score 4):

VonC - switching to -t1 and -t2 fixed the errors. Diffmerge now works for git bash :)

After a little bit of poking at [the gitk patch](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/3/24/1240654) that added External Diff support, I realized that it's calling an External Diff program directly with the two files as arguments. So I modified gitk>Edit>Preferences and put the following command directly into the External Diff Tool option:

```
"C:/Programs/SourceGear/DiffMerge/DiffMerge.exe" -t1="Old Version" -t2="New Version"
```

Now I have DiffMerge working for gitk too :-)

Comment: With latest Diffmerge path is more likely "C:/Program Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe" and -t1/-t2 does not work anymore. If you let that aside you get at least the comparison window