# Getting the whole files history with git-p4

Tags: git, migration, perforce, git-p4

As I've mentioned in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783906/git-under-windows-msys-or-cygwin), I'm looking into migrating our source control from Perforce to git.
Looking around, I've found [git-p4](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools#head-bb56c0cc211da9af16917d005ac59179224373f3) (you have to dig a bit more, since it's not even at the repository pointed by the link. The actual [git-p4 script](http://repo.or.cz/w/git.git?a=blob_plain;f=contrib/fast-import/git-p4;hb=maint) harder to find).

I'm now running this script, and it imports the current version of the files in a new git repository, but I can't manage to get the history, no matter what I do.

Here's the current command line I use is:

```
P4CLIENT=my-p4-clientspec git-p4 clone --max-changes=1000 --use-client-spec //p4/path/to/be/imported/...
```

So, the real question is: if anyone has managed to import a P4 depot, *including the history*, I'd like to know how you did it.

Comment: In nowadays (2018), the main implementation of the [*git-p4* conventions](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4) is [Github's LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try appending "@all" to the file path. For example, this produces a single-revision repo for me:

```
python /usr/share/doc/git-core/contrib/fast-import/git-p4 clone --destination=master-pom \
    //depot/services/master-pom/trunk/...
```

This command imported the full history:

```
python /usr/share/doc/git-core/contrib/fast-import/git-p4 clone --destination=master-pom \
    //depot/services/master-pom/trunk/...@all
```

I tried using the example git-p4 but gave up for several reasons and wrote my own fast-import pump. It was a while back, so some of the problems may have been fixed now: but git-p4 had trouble with large changelists (such as the initial creation of a branch) (although using the client spec may have helped, I don't think I tried it) and files with the "+S" filetype modifier (which is Bad And Evil, but we used to use it). And my Python-fu wasn't up to letting me fix the issues I had.

EDIT: since someone asked for it, here it is.

https://github.com/araqnid/p4utils has several p4 things, of which p4-git-xfer is the p4->git (one-way) replicator. It has quite a few issues though, due to being mainly a personal handy-tool rather than a real piece of infrastructure.

Getting started:

```
p4-git-xfer clone -d $PWD/dictionary.git -n //depot/services/midoffice/dictionary/... \
  trunk 'release/*' 'branch/*' \
  trunk=master release/*=r* branch/*=dev/*
```

will clone that perforce path to a bare "dictionary.git". The first arguments after the base path are "branch specs" that tell the replicator where to find branches under the base. The later ones (with '=' symbols) are "mirror specs" that tell the replicator how to create local branches from the imported ones. The branch specs cause "refs/remotes/p4/trunk", "refs/remotes/p4/release/1.0" etc. to be created. The mirror specs force "refs/heads/master" to mirror "refs/remotes/p4/trunk", "refs/heads/r1.0" to mirror "refs/remotes/p4/release/1.0" etc. It was intended as a way to allow me to select just particular branches from those that were replicated to get propagated to clones.

It will attempt to detect how a branch is created, but that's a bit of a guess anyway with Perforce. Apart from that, it doesn't try to do any branch tracking at all: even whole-branch merges won't be written out as such, sorry.

After the initial clone, running `p4-git-xfer fetch` from inside the git replica will do an incremental update. The high-water-mark changelist is taken from `marks/p4` within the git repo. This is a marks file that fast-import loads, so if you do any fancy footwork like using filter-branch to rewrite things, beware you may have to update this too.

It's not pretty, and has some medium-to-serious issues; I use it mainly for my own convenience, to isolate myself from Perforce problems, not as a day-to-day criticial infrastructure component. It's one-way: I generally use the p4-am script to apply patches created by `git format-patch`. That itself only works mostly, with general parsing nastiness, problems with end-of-file newlines, binary changes etc.

Comment: Is your p4 import script public? If so, would you mind sharing it?

Comment: I have opposite question, I don't want to import all histories, but only last 10 changes for each file. how to do that ?

Comment: You mean append `@all` to the depot path, not the file path.

Answer (score 0):

1. install git bash (cli)
2. install p4 cli
3. install python 2.7
4. get git-p4 script>> http://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/plain/git-p4.py
5. put this script into c/program/files/git/bin/
6. now open git bash or cmd check by typing python done, p4 done, git done, git p4,
7. create client workspace named git .
8. git p4 clone depo/path/@all repo/path

---

just in case doesnt work  set path in environment variables for python if python creates problem
set P4CLIENT=git

Answer (score -3):

The git-p4 help is actually pretty good:

```
man git-p4
```

On Ubuntu 12.04 it is include in the `git-man` package.