# How to get --detect-branches to work with git-p4?

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

My p4 repository has a structure similar to:

```
//depot/project/branch1
//depot/project/branch2
//depot/project/branch3
... etc
```

However, when I use `git-p4` to clone "project", all 3 branches are not considered as branches and all get cloned into the single master branch.

This is how I'm invoking `git-p4`:

```
git-p4 clone --detect-branches //depot/project
```

I was expecting `git-p4` to create a git database for "`project`" with three branches, and the root of the project would be mapped to the portion of the path after the branch name (for example: if `//depot/project/branch1` has a subdirectory called "`lib`" (`//depot/project/branch1/lib`) then my local file system should be something like `/git_project/lib` with 3 git branches).

Is what I'm expecting wrong?  Am I invoking `git-p4` incorrectly?

Comment: Did you ever have any luck, Michael? I'm having a lot of trouble with this, even using branch specs as described on many web sites.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [git-p4 code](http://github.com/jrk/git-p4/blob/master/git-p4) (also [originally here](http://repo.or.cz/w/git.git?a=blob_plain;f=contrib/fast-import/git-p4;hb=maint)), you see:

```
if self.detectBranches:
  branches = self.splitFilesIntoBranches(description)
  for branch in branches.keys():
    ## HACK  --hwn
    branchPrefix = self.depotPaths[0] + branch + "/"
```

with `splitFilesIntoBranches` exploring the p4 repo for branches.

So maybe `git-p4 clone //depot/project@all --detect-branches` would be fine (with the @all as in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786909/getting-the-whole-files-history-with-p4-git), and the `--detect-branches` option after the repo path)?

That being said, if the script is not smart enough to manage that, may be a simpler solution is to run it 3 times, one per branch and import the result in one Git repo.

Comment: I gave the "@all" a try.  However, perhaps it's not working because of parenthesis within other parts of the depot?  The branch mentioned in the output below does not reside within the part of the depot I'm trying to clone (it is higher up).  (I've masked out project names and user names with "PROJECT" and "USER")

Comment: Initialized empty Git repository in /cygdrive/c/projects/PROJECT/.git/
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `p4 -G branch -o dev_OtherProject(ASP.Net)_USER'
Importing revision 181332 (0%)
    Importing new branch PROJECT/Main/dotNet

    Resuming with change 181332
fatal: Invalid ref name or SHA1 expression: refs/remotes/p4/PROJECT/Delivery/dotNet
fast-import: dumping crash report to .git/fast_import_crash_1832

Wouldn't running it 3 times, one per branch, create 3 git repositories?  I thought git-p4 clone always made a new repository.

Answer (score 0):

I just worked on a related bug with `--detect-branches`. The script does a few things:

1. detect the branch names using p4 data
2. create a map of the parent of each branch
3. map the files to a specific branch
4. remove the branch prefix before committing into git

You'll have to follow the code to make sure each step is being done correctly. Using `pdb` to do this works well enough.

Step 1 and 2 is done in `P4Sync.getBranchMapping`

Step 3 is done in `P4Sync.splitFilesIntoBranches`

For step 4. this is done with `P4Sync.stripRepoPath`. Set a break point there, and you can see if the branches have been detected and files are being renamed properly.