# Detect new branches with git-p4?

Tags: git, git-p4

git-p4 is not creating new branches with `git p4 sync`.

We are using branchList config entries (not Perforce branch specifications). I've added a new branch spec to the config, but `git p4 sync --detect-branches` is not adding the new branch.

Is this a situation where `git p4 sync --detect-branches //path/to depot/@all` should be used?

How do I get git p4 sync to detect and add new branches?

Answer (score -1):

This article here shows how to add new branches:

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Git-Fusion-Branch-Mappings

Also the Git Fusion Guide here under 'Converting a lightweight branch into a fully populated Perforce branch':

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/git-fusion/chapter_dyn_ngj_3l.html#section_kkz_gqv_rl

REFERENCES

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Mapping-Git-Terms-and-Commands-to-Perforce

Comment: Provided that git Fusion is similar to git-p4, it sounds like even a simple branch cannot be accounted for after the fact. Adding a branch in git is simple, detecting the branch in p4 must be hard? The branch in question has no merges and is just a basic branch from another already pulled branch.

Comment: Hi @BillDoor I am not sure what you mean by detecting a branch but no it is not difficult to work with branches in Perforce. What exactly are you trying to do and is this in Git-P4 or Perforce?

Comment: Also have you seen these posts? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305357/how-to-clone-branch-with-git-p4  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737999/how-to-get-detect-branches-to-work-with-git-p4