# git-p4: Can't Map File error

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I am using this version of [gitp4.py](https://github.com/MathieuNls/git-p4.py) and I have the following error while trying to clone a repo.

```
  git p4 clone //xxx/xxx@all xxx
    Importing from //xxx/xxx@all into xxx
    Initialized empty Git repository in /cygdrive/d/xxx/.git/
    Import destination: refs/remotes/p4/master
    Importing revision 00000(0%)
    Importing revision 00001(2%) Error from p4 print for //xxx/xxx/xxx/SomeFile.cs: Can't map //yyy/yyy/yyy/SomeFile.cs
```

Note that the root paths are different. It seems that my repo (xxx) contains a file that refers to another repo (yyy). I don't have access to the yyy repo. Is there a way to prevent this error by skipping this revision entirely or deleting this file from the history ?

Thanks,
M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the entire history, you can replace `@all` with a range of revisions.

Otherwise:

1. Ask your p4 admin to give you access to the file.
2. Ask your p4 admin to use `p4 obliterate` to remove the file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do need the all history

Comment: I've added a few perforce options, but both require your perforce admin to do things. Other than that all I can think is changes to git-p4.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/802295/3978 has a link to his tool for doing git-fast-import streams, so maybe that will work?