# Connecting Eclipse drawable folder in an Android project to Dropbox

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm working on an app with graphic designer, who uses Dropbox to share graphic files with me. He shares those files the same I use them in my app (i.e. in `drawable-hdpi`, etc. hierarchy).

Can I "sync" Eclipse with Dropbox that way (only the graphic files and only for the current development)? What I want is Eclipse changing/replacing the file whenever it changes on the Dropbox and possibly also adding the new files for the project drawables whenever there are some new files on a Dropbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use Dropbox as a version control service. This is far from optimal, since Dropbox does not have any of the necessary features (file locking, history, revert support, easy compare tool, etc..).

So I would suggest either:

1. Teach your designer to upload files to SVN, git or whatever version control service you're familiar with. They all have seamless Eclipse integration, and pose no overhead to the designer's work. Most of them have a [free hosting solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317180/revision-control-and-hosting-comparison) as well, if that's an issue.
2. [Share the /res/ directory of your](https://www.dropbox.com/help/19/en) project with your designer, using the [Dropbox Desktop Application](https://www.dropbox.com/install). Since dropbox adds a lot of metadata files to shared dirs, you need to remember [not to include these](http://redwoodr.tumblr.com/post/9062600303/using-dropbox-with-eclipse).