# git archive "The input line is too long. " error in batch file

Tags: windows, git, batch-file

From various sources I managed to modify a script I found to create an archive of the files that were added or changed between 2 changesets. The batch script is as follows:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set output=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('git diff --name-only %1 %2') do ( set output=!output! "%%a" )
git archive -o export.zip HEAD %output%
endlocal
```

This has worked great until today and all of a sudden I am getting the following error back:

> The input line is too long. The syntax of the command is incorrect.

I've confirmed that the cause of this is the that result of %output% is too long but not sure if or how I can work around this?

Comment: Which various sources did you use to put your script together?

Comment: Not sure how it helps but here is one url http://pastebin.com/aZ19cEaD and here is another that I used to help http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive. There were plenty of others I visited also before I got this to work. As a last resort I'm going to have a go at iterating each file and copying it to a folder if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to export changed files between two commits, why not (instead on relying on DOS variable being set, and being potentially too long) do a:

```
git archive --output=file.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only SHA1 SHA2)
```

Since it is an Unix syntax, you need to call the sh.exe included in Git for Windows (as I mention in "[What is the exact meaning of Git Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17810334/6309)")

The [OP ProNotion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/194884/pronotion) proposes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456200/git-archive-the-input-line-is-too-long-error-in-batch-file/24473368#comment37881049_24473368):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c "git archive -o export.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only %1 %2)"
```

Comment: Because $(...) doesn't work in a windows command prompt - at least not for me. The result I get is ```error: unknown option `name-only'```

Comment: @pro it will, in a git bash

Comment: But I don't think then this can be done via a batch file which is the intention as the process is to be automated? I will however explore the option further

Comment: What does work though is calling Bash from the batch file with the command you provided as follows:

```"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c "git archive -o export.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only %1 %2)"```

Comment: @ProNotion Looks good! I have included that command line in the answer for more visibility, as well as a link where I presented before the `sh.exe` included in Git for windows.

Comment: Finding this solution actually proves useful for a number of reasons aside from just my original question as it means I can stop fighting DOS restrictions and just make use of the Git Bash and use my DOS batch files to proxy the commands.

Comment: @ProNotion I agree: nice combination here!

Comment: seems like git archive command has problem if files are too many even with this method.