# Using $ as parameter instead of directive in Cruise Control

Tags: git, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I have been trying to use $ for buildArgs command

```
<buildArgs>git archive -o myfile.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only remotes/origin/master)</buildArgs>
```

Cruise control is treating $ as a directive to resolve the symbol and giving error
Internal Error: Reference to unknown symbol

Is there any way I can use $ as a symbol?

Comment: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228186.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383819.aspx

Comment: Thanks @stijn, I tried using %24 but it doesn't seems to work inside git command prompt

Comment: In that case you should post the error, and you probably should formulate your question differently: your problem isn't just how to pass $ to the commandline but rather how to get this commandline executed on windows, right? $ works in bash and other shells, not on the windows commandline, so you have to find the equivalent, or pass the entire thing through sh.exe (or powershell should also work). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456200/git-archive-the-input-line-is-too-long-error-in-batch-file/24473368

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing `$` with `\$` so instead of

```
git archive -o myfile.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only remotes/origin/master)
```

You could use

```
git archive -o myfile.zip HEAD \$(git diff --name-only remotes/origin/master)
```

This is the way to escape the $ character in bash, and although cruise control doesn't execute in the bash prompt, it will pass the arguments to git, see [quoting and escaping in bash](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting)