# Run a precommit hook in Git. Is there a way to verify that the script is running?

Tags: git, githooks, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I wanted to run a Git and as suggested by the blogs, I used `$git init` to initialize the repository and then a `.git` folder is created where the hooks are present in the hooks directory. Then as suggested by the script I renamed `pre-commit.sample as pre-commit` it didn't work so I renamed it as `pre-commit.sh` it still didn't seem to be running in the background or I atleast didn't know it did.

So, in order to have a clue as to whether it was running in the background I used an echo statement but I never showed up. Feeling lost, I next tried to manually run the script `.\pre-commit.sh` in powershell the echo statement was not printed on console. For one, I don't know if the console will be displayed even if the echo statement is successful by halting the progress of the script with a input feed from the user.

So please do tell me -- how to setup a pre-commit hook? Did I misread the procedure? Am I missing something here? Please do let me know.

The hook that I am using is a default pre-commit hook implementation by just for convenience I'll put it here -- hope it

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# An example hook script to verify what is about to be committed.
# Called by "git commit" with no arguments.  The hook should
# exit with non-zero status after issuing an appropriate message if
# it wants to stop the commit.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "pre-commit".

if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    against=HEAD
else
    # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
    against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
fi

# If you want to allow non-ASCII filenames set this variable to true.
allownonascii=$(git config --bool hooks.allownonascii)

# Redirect output to stderr.
exec 1>&2

# Cross platform projects tend to avoid non-ASCII filenames; prevent
# them from being added to the repository. We exploit the fact that the
# printable range starts at the space character and ends with tilde.
if [ "$allownonascii" != "true" ] &&
    # Note that the use of brackets around a tr range is ok here, (it's
    # even required, for portability to Solaris 10's /usr/bin/tr), since
    # the square bracket bytes happen to fall in the designated range.
    test $(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=A -z $against |
      LC_ALL=C tr -d '[ -~]\0' | wc -c) != 0
then
    cat <<\EOF
Error: Attempt to add a non-ASCII file name.

This can cause problems if you want to work with people on other platforms.

To be portable it is advisable to rename the file.

If you know what you are doing you can disable this check using:

  git config hooks.allownonascii true
EOF
    exit 1
fi

# If there are whitespace errors, print the offending file names and fail.
exec git diff-index --check --cached $against --
```

Comment: As indicated in the file, the required name is "pre-commit", not "precommit" or "precommit.sh".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can add a simple echo.

Second, the script will be run by the [msys bash-like shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17810334/6309), so you can't run it directly from a PowerShell Windows session.

Third, make sure you did add some elements to the index in order for the git commit to have something to commit (and for the pre-commit hook to have a reason to be triggered).

---

[dennis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1992360/dennis) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188028/run-a-precommit-hook-in-git-is-there-a-way-to-verify-that-the-script-is-running/25225689?noredirect=1#comment39559377_25225689):

> - it should be renamed as "`pre-commit`" and not "`pre-commit.sh`" and
> - the script does run and display the echo-ed statement on commandprompt / powershell.

Comment: Hi! It works...it does work with the steps mentioned except for the part that it should be renamed as "pre-commit" and not "pre-commit.sh" and the script does run and display the echo-ed statement on commandprompt / powershell -- I thought you'd like to know. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @dennis Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: the echo works because that specific command is recognized by both cmd, powershell and bash. Otherwise, you were right it doesn't work