# how can we use linux commands on windows through git?

Tags: git

> "We all use linux commands in git even in windows. I wanted to know how does it let these linux commands run on windows?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `<c:\path\to\git\bin>` to your `%PATH%` and you can use the Unix command [packaged with msysgit](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases).

For instance, `ls` or `grep` would work.

```
C:\prgs>which ls
C:\prgs\git\PortableGit-1.9.5-preview20141217\bin\ls.EXE
```

Those commands are part of the [MinGw/msys project](http://www.mingw.org/welcome_to_mingw_org) which provides a minimalist development environment for native Microsoft Windows applications.

That is what is used to build git itself, and its collection of Linux commands (as Windows executable).

See more at:

- "[Difference between msysgit and Cygwin + git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3144417/6309)".
- "[What is the exact meaning of Git Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17810334/6309)"

Comment: I wanted to know how is it possible to use linux commands on windows? What is the mechanism?

Comment: @SumitDutta Someone took the source code for various utilities/tool/commands that are common on linux and compiled them on windows, and included those windows executables in the msysgit package

Comment: thanx @VonC, now I got what i was searching for.