# git ls-tree -rd works bizzare in a subdirectory

Tags: git

Say I have a repo with these files:

```
aaa.txt
f1/bbb.txt
f1/f2/ccc.txt
```

If my CWD is the top of working tree, I get this result:

```
$ git ls-tree -r --name-only $(git write-tree)
aaa.txt
f1/bbb.txt
f1/f2/ccc.txt

$ git ls-tree -rd --name-only $(git write-tree)
f1
f1/f2
```

If my CWD is in the `f1` directory, I get this result:

```
$ git ls-tree -r --name-only $(git write-tree)
bbb.txt
f2/ccc.txt

$ git ls-tree -rd --name-only $(git write-tree)
```

I expect `git ls-tree -rd --name-only $(git write-tree)` to return `f2`. However the result is empty. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might be an issue linked to the old [msysgit 32bits Git For Windows 1.9.5](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases), where I did reproduce the same issue.

I just tested it in a git bash session using the [new msys2 64bits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17810334/6309) [Git For Windows 2.3.5](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/), and it works perfectly.

```
VonC@voncvb MINGW64 /c/Users/VonC/prog/go/src/github.com/VonC/senvgo (master)
$ git ls-tree -rd --name-only $(git write-tree)
.deps
.deps/godbg
configs
envs
installer
paths
paths/7z
prgs

VonC@voncvb MINGW64 /c/Users/VonC/prog/go/src/github.com/VonC/senvgo (master)
$ cd paths/

VonC@voncvb MINGW64 /c/Users/VonC/prog/go/src/github.com/VonC/senvgo/paths (master)
$ git ls-tree -rd --name-only $(git write-tree)
./
7z
```

Comment: You are right. It seems to work in a later version of git. However it seems to output directories in the whole repo instead of the childs of CWD, and there are extra `./` when CWD is `f1` and `../` and `./` when CWD is `f1/f2`. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @DannyLin I am sorry I missed your comment. I didn't see a way to change the output (the `-r` option does ls the tree recursively). Did you manage to get the expected output?

Comment: No. I just wonder whether it's a bug or I'm doing something wrong. It seems that I have to filter starting ./ and ../ out if I'm going to make it work currently.