# error: Cannot call method 'substr' of null, azure file upload

Tags: bash, azure, azure-cli

I'm trying to upload some zip files to Azure blob storage using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Sample script to upload a file to a BLOB container 

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "Please specify a filename"
    exit 1
fi

# Required parameters
file_name=$1
azure_account=xxx
azure_key=xxx
container_name=xxx
blob_name=xxx

# Used by azure-cli
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT=$azure_account
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY=$azure_key

azure storage blob upload $file_name $container_name $blob_name
```

But whenever I run it I get:

> sh upload-file.sh file.zip info:    Executing command storage blob
>   upload error:   Cannot call method 'substr' of null info:    Error
>   information has been recorded to /home/usr/.azure/azure.err error:
>   storage blob upload command failed

Comment: Tried running with the bash shell, i.e `bash upload-file.sh file.zip`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're on Windows. The following works from PowerShell on my machine.

```
sh upload-file.sh file.zip
```

The `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of your script means [that it is supposed to use `bash` to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash). **Do you have bash installed?** Check via `bash --version`.

```
> bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.1.23(6)-release (i686-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

If you do not have bash then install it. The way that I installed `bash` on Windows was via [msysGit](http://www.git-scm.com/downloads). This installs what is called [git-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807485/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-git-bash) along with Git for Windows. There are other ways to install bash on Windows such as [win-bash](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/) and [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), though I do not have any familiarity with those.

Comment: I forgot to specify I was running it on a virtualbox ubuntu server instance. with bash version 4.3.11.