# Is there a way to commit external files into current repository?

Tags: git

I have a Git repository **d:\repositories\temp** and a directory **d:\temp1**, and I want to achieve this: All changes in the directory **d:\temp1** can be detected and committed to the repository **d:\repositories\temp** (local and remote). Is it possible? Thanks.

***Note***: The feature I need here may be similar as the external links of SVN.

Comment: About the content of temp1: should it be compared to the full content of the repo ? or to a subfolder of the repo ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare `d:\temp1` as:

- a repository itself (`git init .`) in order to record its changes
- a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)** of `d:\repositories\temp`

  ```
  git submodule add -b master -- /d/temp1
  git submodule update --init
  ```

See "[true nature of submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194)":

- `temp1` would become a subfolder of `d:\repositories\temp`,
- any change made in `d:\temp1` can be committed, and updated in `d:\repositories\temp\temp1` after a `git submodule update --remote`

That way, at any point, `temp` records the exact state of `temp1` it is working with (I prefer that [to a subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31770147/6309))
As I mentioned in "[SVN:externals equivalent in GIT?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18088319/6309)", this is close to `svn:external`, even though it is [not completely the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3132221/6309).

Note that if you push `temp` to GitHub, you will see `temp1` as a gray folder: That gray folder is a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** (a [special entry in the parent index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309))

If you clone that GitHub repo with the --recursive option, you will get back the content of `temp1`, because Git will be able to clone back `/d/temp1`.
...
However, nobody else would be able to clone your GitHub repo *and* get that `temp1` content, since they don't have access to your `/d` disk!

In order to preserve the content of a submodule, it is best if `temp1` itself is first pushed to its own GitHub repo, and `temp` reference `temp1` through its GitHub url (and not through a local path `/d/temp1`).
[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/914090/6309) to change the url of submodule `temp1`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. When I executed the command `git submodule add -b master -- d:\temp1` at `d:\repositories\temp`, the following message display "repo URL: 'master' must be absolute or begin with ./|../", do you know how to resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: @RayChen try instead a relative path: `../../temp1`

Comment: Hi, VonC. The messages changed as `"fatal: repository 'https://github.com/temp1/' not found"` and `"fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/temp1' into submodule path 'temp1' failed"`.

Comment: @RayChen what `git remote -v` (done in both repo) return? Are those repos cloned from GitHub?

Comment: The `d:\temp1` is only a local Git here, it has no remote. I don't know whether this fact causes this error.

Comment: What if you use `/d/temp1` as the submodule path?

Comment: Running the command `git remote -v` at `d:\repositories\temp` returns `origin  https://github.com/raychen518/temp.git (fetch)` and `origin  https://github.com/raychen518/temp.git (push)`, while running at `d:\temp1` returns nothing (there is no any display).

Comment: @RayChen maybe try a specify the protocol: `file://../../temp1`

Comment: @Pockets Thanks. I run the command `git submodule add -b master -- /d/temp1` and it seemed succeeded. A folder named `temp1` and a file named `.gitmodules` were created under `d:\repositories\temp`. But that folder `temp1` does not contain content of `d:\temp1`, do you know why?

Comment: @VonC Thanks for the update. I created a directory `d:\temp2` and follow your updated steps again. This time there is no error, but the created `temp2` folder under `d:\repositories\temp` is still empty (the directory `d:\temp2` actually has some content). Do you know why? Thanks.

Comment: @RayChen You need to add and commit in `temp2` first, then go back to `'d:\repositories\temp`, and do a `git submodule update --remote` (then, since temp2 SHA1 will have changed, add, commit and push)

Comment: @vonc FWIW The reason it has to use the Unix-style filepath is because Git for Windows runs on top of the MSYS2 POSIX emulation environment.

Comment: @Pockets True. I should have known, I documented that a long time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35099458/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/a/17810334/6309, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3144417/6309

Comment: @VonC Thanks for your patient help. I created several new directories and followed the updated steps again, now after I changed and committed (only to local) content in those new directories, I can get that changed content in corresponding directories under `d:\repositories\temp`. But, when I commit `d:\repositories\temp` to remote, only those corresponding directories are committed, content of them are not committed. And I checked the remote at GitHub, those gitmodule directories are there but cannot be clicked into, and they are displayed with strange suffixes (such as @ fb9038d).

Comment: @RayChen I have edited the answer to address the gray folder issue. Also, re-read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194 to understand what submodules are all about.

Comment: @VonC Thanks for the update. I have seen that updated answer and basically understand it. Maybe finally I will create a batch file to copy all external files to the repository and then commit (_because I do not want to create remote Git repositories for all my external files which are under different unrelated directories, it is troublesome for me_). Let me consider it~ Thanks greatly for all the help. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Git has a feature called submodule that can be used to achieve what you are trying to achieve, Here have a look at this https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Yes, I just mentioned submodules, with a lot of links to illustrate its subtle differences with svn externals.

Comment: yeah i just looked