# git failing to find the index when in submodule ("index file open failed: not a directory")

Tags: git, git-submodules

On a fresh git repo, after adding a submodule and changing to the submodule directory most git commands fail when run within the submodule with the error:

```
fatal: index file open failed: Not a directory
```

The full set of commands to reproduce the issue:

```
>  git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/drh/code/personal/Experiments/git-test/.git/
>  git status
On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
>  git submodule add git@github.com:mitsuhiko/flask.git thirdparty/flask
Cloning into 'thirdparty/flask'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 9959, done.
remote: Total 9959 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (9959/9959), 5.17 MiB | 1.11 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5617/5617), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
>  cd thirdparty/flask
>  git status
fatal: index file open failed: Not a directory
>  cat .git
gitdir: ../../.git/modules/thirdparty/flask
```

git version 1.8.5.2 running on Mavericks

Comment: Just to experiment ... I tried symlinking .git to the correct directory (../../.git/modules/thirdparty/flask) which resolves the immediate problem of the index file open failing, but it seems to mess with how git detects the dirty state of the submodule and probably has other negative side-effects

Comment: Solved this. To close the loop for anyone else this was fixed by opening a new terminal session. I suspect it was some sort of weird state with some git environment variables (maybe GIT_DIR).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because there isn't a commit yet in the parent repo (meaning no HEAD, and [no `master` branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)).
As you have detected, the `GIT_DIR` for the parent repo might be set too late for the submodule to use.
That would be a [good bug to report](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10733251/6309) if [none of the git submodule tests](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t7400-submodule-basic.sh) cover that scenario.

Or, as the [OP user3184153](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3184153/user3184153) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058363/git-failing-to-find-the-index-when-in-submodule-index-file-open-failed-not-a/21060207?noredirect=1#comment31827177_21060207):

> I think that some other application (I suspecting `virtualenv`, though can't reproduce) was setting `GIT_DIR`.

Comment: Hmmm thanks for the assist, though I just tried this with a new repo and it did work even with no commit in the parent repo. I think that some other application (I suspecting virtualenv, though cant reproduce) was setting GIT_DIR

Comment: @user3184153 Ok. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 3):

I personally was seeing this problem in my pre-commit hooks for some submodule automation. Environment variables `GIT_DIR`, `GIT_WORK_TREE`, `GIT_INDEX_FILE`, etc.. were causing the issue. I was able to fix this problem with `env -i git <git-command>`, which is a simple way to use a clean bash enviornment with a single command.