# How to open an issue on "git"?

Tags: git

NOTE: I know this may be offtopic for this site but please tell me where I can post it if not appropriate

I had several issues with "git" itself - especially git diff - (which I think are not always due to me) so I'd like to open an issue on the tool itself whose code is open source.

This is what I found:

> https://github.com/git/git

but no "issues" tab. 
Is the mailing list the only tool to communicate with them?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/community

Comment: what kind of issues have you been having?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728104/where-can-i-report-a-git-bug

Comment: I finally posted it here https://github.com/git/git-scm.com/issues/772 @saq7 you can see there