# git@vger.kernel.org email issues / bug reports ignored

Tags: git

I'm trying to raise 3 issues to the git mailing list at: `git@vger.kernel.org`.

One of them deomonstrates git trying to execute output.

My mail hasn't gone through when I [search for my name](https://marc.info/?l=git&w=2&r=1&s=tom+hale&q=b).

I even tried subscribing to the list, and resending, but no joy.

The same problem occurred in 2018, but I choose to ignore it then.

How do I get my email to be accepted on `git@vger.kernel.org`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a computer programming question. It's a question about the engineering system of one specific project.

Comment: It's a question about how to get `git` working.  What would be a more appropriate SE site, @RaymondChen?

Comment: As written, it's a question about how to send email to the git mailing list. If you have a question about getting git working, you can ask it here.

Comment: @Raymond Chen: The former is necessary for the latter.

Comment: If the question really is about "how to get git working" (how to set it up), then that question is on-topic for this site. If the question is "how to report a bug in git", then [that's answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10733251/902497), including reasons why your message might not show up.

Comment: I read your linked answer. This question is about a problem in actioning the advice given there.