# Git tree object and git terminology

Tags: git, version-control

I've been learning about git and I'm quite confused by the terminology.

Do I understand it properly that a "tree object" is really something like a "folder object"? It keeps information of things inside it (blobs) and other trees (sub-folders). It keeps information about the "actual data" of the project we are working on.

At the same time, the structure of commits/versions has a tree like structure (directed acyclic graph really, with merges, but that's just a detail), and paths to a leaf in this tree could be called branches. "Branches" in git however, are actually just pointers to commits though.

Do I understand this right? Is it just me or is "tree objects" a pretty misleading name, given the already existing tree structure of the "version tree structure" ? Even if you wanted to use the word tree, it would make more sense to call it "tree node object" or something - since a tree object in git doesn't seem to contain a whole tree, just some blobs and a pointer to other trees. The name branches also seems misleading, for similar reasons.

Comment: Incidentally, for more about the poor overworked word "tree" in VCSes and in computing / informatics in general, see the side note currently on p. 21 [here](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf).

Comment: Might as well complain about the use of the word "set".  There's lots of words that need context to disambiguate. Once you've learned to be comfortable with `K` meaning variously potassium, kelvin, kilo (both 1000 and 1024) generally, kilometers specifically, and vastly more, all the context-dependent uses of "tree" won't be hard to get on top of.

Comment: @jthill I partly just wanted to check whether I get the basic structure of git right, and I'm not complaining or implying it should be done some other way. If some programming language decides to use the word "linked list" for the node of linked list, I think it's ok to wonder whether that isn't misleading, ask about it, and see if maybe you're not missing some reason why it makes perfect sense to call it "linked list". That's really what I'm  doing - I want to make sure I understand it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for the user-facing documentation's insistence on using the word *tree-ish* (if that even *is* a word), the term *tree* is internal to Git, so it shouldn't matter what they call it: *tree*, or [*marplot*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marplot), or [*gripsack*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/gripsack), or whatever you like.

That said, a tree object, inside Git, is simply one of the four object types.  What it contains is a series of entries, with each entry holding three items:

- a mode: an octal number, terminated with ASCII space, with no leading zeros, that describes the type of the entry and gives the `x` bit for regular files;
- a name: a byte-sequence terminated with an ASCII NUL (`'\0'` in C, `b'\0'` in Python); and
- a raw hash ID: 20 unencoded bytes.<sup>1</sup>

The name in a tree object is really just a *name component*.  If the mode entry is `40000`, the hash ID must be that of another tree object.  If the mode is `120000`, `100644`, or `100755`, the hash ID must be that of a blob object.  If the mode is `160000`, the hash ID is expected to be a commit object as stored in some other Git repository, i.e., a *gitlink*.  Other modes are generally not allowed, though `git fsck` allows `100664` as this mode appears in some existing (very old) repositories.

The file name of a blob or (mode `120000`) symbolic link is constructed by stringing together the name components of the tree objects that led to the blob, with slashes appended, and then adding the last component in the final tree object.  That is, if the top-level tree object for some commit is T<sub>0</sub>, and the blob or symlink appears directly *in* T<sub>0</sub>, then the entry gives the name of the file that will hold the blob or symlink.

But if T<sub>0</sub> has an entry `foo` with mode `40000` and hash T<sub>1</sub>, Git will go on to read tree object T<sub>1</sub>.  If *that* has an entry `bar` with mode `100xxx` or `120000`, the blob object will be a file or symlink whose name is `foo/bar`.  Hence the file's path name is produced by traversing tree objects until reaching a leaf.

For a gitlink (tree entity with mode `160000`), the constructed path name gives the submodule path that Git will check for in `.gitmodules`, if we must clone the submodule, and the hash ID is the commit we'll `git checkout` as a detached HEAD in that other Git repository.  For all other entities, the hash ID should be that of an object in *this* Git repository, otherwise the tree object is incorrect or the repository is inconsistent (or both).

As someone using Git, you do not have to care about any of this: just put files in the index as usual, and use `git write-tree` to write everything.  Use `git read-tree` to grab a tree by the hash ID in a commit, to fill the index<sup>2</sup> from that tree.  Use `git show` or `git cat-file` to obtain a single file's contents using either a hash ID (blob hash) or a path name (`commit-hash:path`, which `git rev-parse` can translate, and for a long time now, `git cat-file` can handle as well).

---

<sup>1</sup>This is kind of a mistake, because when Git goes to using longer hash IDs in the future, either the tree objects may have to store truncated hashes, or we'll need a new flavor of tree object.  Note that Mercurial's internal tree data structures left more room.  Git probably should have used an ASCII-ized hex digest terminated by another NUL.  But there are enough other thorny issues here to be resolve that this one is kind of minor.

<sup>2</sup>If you set `GIT_INDEX_FILE`, `git read-tree` will read the tree into the alternate index whose path name you provided.

Comment: Tree-ish is using a convention from I think the Algol 68 report, maybe even older, the `-ish` usage on the end meaning anything that can be unambiguously converted to one.  So commits and most tags are also tree-ish.

Comment: @jthill: sure, but the point is that this introduces the term *tree* (or tree-ish) to the end user. Fortunately the gitglossary has a definition (for tree, tree object, and tree-ish). Unfortunately not enough Git pages have cross-references to gitglossary.

Answer (score 1):

The [very first commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290) of the Git repository (Apr. 8th, 2005) referenced a "tree object" as

> a list of permission/name/blob data, sorted by name.
>   In other words the tree object is uniquely determined by the set contents, and so
>   two separate but identical trees will always share the exact same object.

[10 days later](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6ad6d3d36c5924c8ff502ebbb6a6216df01e7efb):

> A "tree" object is an object that ties one or more "blob" objects into a directory structure. In addition, a tree object can refer to other tree
>   objects, thus creating a directory hierarchy.

I [mentioned last month](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10733251/6309) an upcoming Git 2.25 tutorial  on object enumeration ([commit e0479fa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0479fa07387a7f84dad04a258cd2dc2861c9df9)) which uses the trees.

> The object walk is a key concept in Git - this is the process that underpins
>   operations like object transfer and fsck.
>   Beginning from a given commit, the list of objects is found by walking parent relationships between commits (commit `X` based on commit `W`) and containment relationships between objects (tree `Y` is contained within commit `X`, and blob `Z` is located within tree `Y`, giving our working tree for commit `X` something like `y/z.txt`).