# git: includeIf not working with git clone

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys, git-config

**.gitconfig**:

```sh
[user]
    name = Dr.jacky
    email = personal.email@gmail.com
    signingKey = ""
[includeIf "gitdir:/Users/drjacky/Projects/CompanyName/"]
    path = /Users/drjacky/gitconfigcompanyname/.gitconfig
[core]
    excludesfile = /Users/drjacky/.gitignore_global
    autocrlf = input
[difftool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = opendiff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
    path = 
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = /Applications/Sourcetree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" -ancestor \"$BASE\" -merge \"$MERGED\"
    trustExitCode = true
[commit]
    template = /Users/drjacky/.stCommitMsg
    gpgSign = false
[gpg]
    program = gpg
[tag]
    forceSignAnnotated = false
```

**gitconfigcompanyname/.gitconfig**:

```sh
[user]
    name = My Name
    email = my.company.email@company.com
```

**.ssh/config**:

```sh
# --- Sourcetree Generated ---
Host Personal-GitHub
    HostName github.com
    User Drjacky
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
# IdentityFile /Users/drjacky/.ssh/Personal-GitHub
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    UseKeychain yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
# ----------------------------
# Company Work GitHub
Host github.com/Company
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_companyname
    UseKeychain yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
```

I've added the second ssh pub via `ssh-add`.

Now, on the terminal/iTerm2, I redirect to `/Users/drjacky/Projects/CompanyName/HERE`, then run this:
`git clone httpUrlOfMyCompanyRepo` or `git clone sshOfMyCompanyRepo`; Doesn't matter, it doesn't have access:

> remote: Repository not found.
> fatal: repository 'https://github.com/CompanyName/reponame.git/' not found

And when I run `git config user.email`, under CompanyName folder path, it shows my personal email.

When I run `git config --list`:

```sh
credential.helper=osxkeychain
user.name=Dr.jacky
user.email=personal.email@gmail.com
user.signingkey=
includeif.gitdir:/Users/drjacky/Projectz/CompanyName/.path=/Users/drjacky/gitconfigcompanyname/.gitconfig
core.excludesfile=/Users/drjacky/.gitignore_global
core.autocrlf=input
difftool.sourcetree.cmd=opendiff "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
difftool.sourcetree.path=
mergetool.sourcetree.cmd=/Applications/Sourcetree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" -ancestor "$BASE" -merge "$MERGED"
mergetool.sourcetree.trustexitcode=true
commit.template=/Users/drjacky/.stCommitMsg
commit.gpgsign=false
gpg.program=gpg
tag.forcesignannotated=false
(END)
```

`git bugreport`:

```sh
[System Info]
git version:
git version 2.28.0
cpu: x86_64
no commit associated with this build
sizeof-long: 8
sizeof-size_t: 8
shell-path: /bin/sh
uname: Darwin 19.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Sun Jul  5 00:43:10 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.141.1~9/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
compiler info: clang: 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
libc info: no libc information available
$SHELL (typically, interactive shell): /bin/zsh
```

**Notes**:

- I've uninstalled SourceTree but didn't help.
- git version 2.28.0
- After cloning the repo with a tool successfully, it works with the correct without a problem.

**Update:**
I've check SSH section on Github dashboard, and it shows the SSH key has not been used at all!

[image]

Comment: you got credentials set up to access that repo, right?

Comment: @eftshift0 Yes, I use the same RSA keys on GitKraken(and before on SourceTree) to clone repos. They worked on those tools correctly.

Comment: Ok.... but did you set them up so that git can use them? In my case, I need to run `ssh-add` providing the private key to be able to access our repos with git.

Comment: @eftshift0 Yes, I've added them as I mentioned in the question. I followed this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3486339/421467. When I run `ssh-add -l` it shows both keys with the emails.

Comment: @eftshift0 Please look at the updated question. The key has not been used at all! But, I added it before. And now, I created a new pub/private key and used them but problem still exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to change `Host github.com/Company` to `Host github.com-Company` in `ssh/config`.
Then, clone like this:
`git clone git@github.com-Company:Company/repoName.git`

<s>But, still prefer to have a better solution, instead of changing ssh address / HTTP URL.</s>

Sources:

- https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996
- https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996#gistcomment-826728

**Update:**

According to this [comment](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996#gistcomment-3418552):
Personal `.gitconfig` for personal/everything else projects:

```bash
[user]
    name = Dr.jacky
    email = email@personal.com
[core]
    sshCommand = ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -F /dev/null
```

Work `.gitconfig` for company projects:

```bash
[user]
    name = Work Name
    email = work@company.com
[core]
    sshCommand = ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_companyname -F /dev/null
```

And changed the global `.gitconfig` to this:

```bash
[user]
    name = Dr.jacky
    email = email@personal.com
    signingKey = ""
[includeIf "gitdir:/Users/drjacky/*"]
    path = /Users/drjacky/gitconfigpersonal/.gitconfig
[includeIf "gitdir:/Users/drjacky/Projectz/CompanyName/"]
    path = /Users/drjacky/gitconfigcompanyname/.gitconfig
```

Thanks to [leddzip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14095023/leddzip)!

Comment: For anyone else using `.gitconfig` to switch ssh identities, it didn't work for me until I removed all keys from the ssh agent.  Otherwise, doing a git clone via ssh always used the first key the agent already had.  As only git was using ssh keys in my system, I was fine with managing the ssh identities completely via `.gitconfig`.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, Dr.jacky's solution didn't work for my case.

I ended up using `url.<base>.insteadOf` and `url.<base>.pushInsteadOf` in `.gitconfig` + `~/.ssh/config`

`url.<base>.insteadOf` and `url.<base>.pushInsteadOf` can update the github url on the fly

For example, following `.gitconfig` snippet can update the `git clone git@github.com:company/xxxx` dynamically to `git clone git@github.com-company:company/xxxx`

```
[url "git@github.com-company:company"]
    insteadOf = git@github.com:company
    pushInsteadOf = git@github.com:company
```

and with the `~/.ssh/config` from original post

```
# Company Work GitHub
Host github.com/Company
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_companyname
    UseKeychain yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
```

git can pick the right ssh key without any issue.