# Github and Git - what is needed to work with a git terminal in win7?

Tags: git, github

I want to cooperate with a team that is using git on their private server. What to I need to push and pull from there server? I got win7, what do I need? I found a download at [github](https://windows.github.com/) and at [git](https://git-scm.com/download/win).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend the [latest from git-for-windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) ([which will replace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/784743/6309) the [old msysgit soon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3144417/6309), and will include [a more recent bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309)):

- Uncompress [PortableGit-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.5.windows.1/PortableGit-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want
- add `C:\path\to\PortableGit-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit\bin` to your `%PATH%`
- use `<PortableGit-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit>\git-cmd.bat` (regular CMD session) or `<PortableGit-2.4.5.1-4th-release-candidate-64-bit>\git-bash.bat` (shell unix session)
- type:

  ```
  git config --global user.name <yourUsername>
  git config --global user.email <yourEmail>
  git config --global core.autocrlf false
  ```

And you are good to go.
If you have access to that private server, you can clone it (ssh or https url).