# Unset core.editor in Msysgit

Tags: text-editor, msysgit

I set my editor per an SO entry: [How do I setup DiffMerge with msysgit / gitk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780425/how-do-i-setup-diffmerge-with-msysgit-gitk).

I'm wondering how to undo this because I want to switch back to the default editing program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on how you ran git config...

```
git config --unset core.editor
```

Or

```
git config --global --unset core.editor
```