# Linux Editor that can highlight all instances of a selected word

Tags: linux, editor, syntax-highlighting

Is there an editor in Linux that can highlight all instances of a word when the word is double-clicked? I was using Notepad++ in Windows which provided that feature. Now I am missing it in Linux editors. I tried Kate, Gedit, etc.

Comment: Select a word and doing Ctrl+K works in gedit. But can this be done by double clicking alone.

Comment: [Here is a more modern, and canonical answer I just wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67016551/4561887).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VIM can do this:)Not by clicking, but there is a way to quickly search for a word and highlight all occurrences.

Check this out:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip14

Comment: Lol at the continued partisan nature of ?n?x text editors, but more so, lol at this being the accepted answer despite admitting it doesn't answer the question posed

Answer (score 49):

To enable this feature in Geany do the following:

- Install the addons plugin: `sudo apt-get install geany-plugin-addons`
- In Geany, click on `Tools` -> `Plugin Manager`
- enable the plugin `Addons` (check in the column `Active`)
- configure the plugin by clicking on `Preferences`
- enable the option `Mark all occurrences of a word when double-clicking it`

Comment: What's the best way to *un*highlight all words again? In Notepad++, you just click away. In Geany, it seems you must double-click the word again to de-select it. Is there another way, or a better way?

Comment: This is straightforward way of it. thanks m13r, for answer.

Comment: Per @GabrielStaples question, the plugin now has "Deselect a previous highlight by single click". Enable it too and highlight/unhighlight works just like Notepad++

Comment: Geany didn't cut it for me when I entered the world as a professional software developer. So, I just wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556272/linux-editor-that-can-highlight-all-instances-of-a-selected-word/67016551#67016551) to summarize my experiences over the last several years.

Answer (score 10):

First install the addons plugin:

```
sudo apt-get install geany-plugin-addons
```

and then apply the answer of mr13.

Answer (score 4):

What version of Kate where you using, Kate has that exact feature as described [here](http://kate-editor.org/2010/11/14/highlight-selected-text/).

Comment: It only highlights it, but doesn't multi-select. You can't do much with that, certainly not a multi-edit like with Ctrl-D in vscode.

Answer (score 2):

This Geany addon didn't work for me (on Fedora), rather this one did: http://sourceforge.net/projects/geanyhighlightselectedword/. Though installing it was a bit complicated.

Comment: Can you please tell how to install it?

Comment: 1. First you have to build Geany from source (and install its prerequisities, as described in installThesePackagesFirst.sh).
2. Then change MAKEFILE of GeanyHighlightSelectedWord according to your path.
3. Then it will generate GeanyHighlightSelectedWord.so, which you will have to copy to /usr/local/lib/geany.
4. Then you can delete the sources and select it in Geany (Tools > Plugin Manager).

Comment: ok thanks for answer but geany now provides a preinstalled plugin for this

Comment: Great, but where, how to turn it on?. I installed Geany just a few days ago on my Ubuntu 10.04 and I don't find.

Comment: i am using version 14.04 LTS. In that it is there. But i am not sure about version 10.04. Anyways do this. go to Tools->Plugin Manager->(window pops up). The very first plugin is Addons which has various smalls addons for Geany. There you will also find under Addons tab option "Mark all occurences of a word when double-clicking it". Mark it checked and your plugin will be enabled. But this is for ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Apparently this plugin only works with the gtk2 version of geany which was dropped with version1.38. Using version geany 1.37 and compiling with `--enable-gtk2` installation can be done with `gcc -Wall -DGEANY_VERSION_NUMBER=0x128 -g -c GeanyHighlightSelectedWord.c -fPIC  `pkg-config --cflags geany` && gcc -Wall -g GeanyHighlightSelectedWord.o  -o GeanyHighlightSelectedWord.so -shared `pkg-config --libs geany` && sudo cp GeanyHighlightSelectedWord.so  /usr/local/lib/geany/`

Answer (score 1):

## Summary

**Eclipse** has something similar. Install the Darkest Dark plugin, then double-click a word and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to highlight all instances. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to unhighlight.

Both **Sublime Text 3 and 4** and **Microsoft Visual Studio Code (VSCode)** have the double-click feature. Just double-click any word to highlight all instances of it. Click away *anywhere* to unhighlight.

---

## Details

The top 3 modern, Linux-compatible editors which come to my mind when I think about software development are the following. All 3 of them are powerful, modern, widely-used, and cross-platform (Windows, Mac, and Linux)!

1. [**Eclipse**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software))

   1. free and open source software (FOSS), and no-cost, but very heavy.
   2. My go-to and primary editor for professional and hobby software development because it's got an outstanding, world-class indexer which allows you to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> on any variable or function name to jump to its definition.
   3. Links to my full setup documentation are found [here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/eclipse).
2. [**Sublime Text 3 and 4**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text)

   1. proprietary/closed-source *shareware*, a professional and very powerful and very *light-weight* tool, no-cost for an unlimited full-access trial period, and relatively low-cost for a license
   2. My primary editor for individual files--I frequently edit the same file at the same time with both Eclipse and Sublime Text 3 and 4, since Sublime has wonderful multi-cursor support for simultaneous editing of multiple lines all at once! I also have Eclipse set as my git editor of choice (see my answer here: [How do I make git use the editor of my choice for commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits/48212377#48212377))
   3. Learn to use it with this live, interactive tutorial-style "plugin": https://sublimetutor.com/.
3. [**Microsoft Visual Studio Code (VSCode)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)

   1. free and open source source (FOSS) source code, and no-cost; minor caveat: technically, the binaries distributed by Microsoft are freeware, though the source code is free and open source
   2. One of the industry's most popular editors today, but also a relatively new entry into the field. I haven't used it much yet.

So, let's see how each of these 3 can "highlight all instances of a selected word":

### 1. Eclipse

1. If you install the plugin [Darkest Dark Theme with DevStyle](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme-devstyle), you get the following features:

   1. Just place your cursor on any variable and it automatically highlights all instances of this variable, like this. Here you can see `_currentChannel_i` highlighted in black in 4 places, and in some yellowish color in one place near the bottom-left: [image]
   2. [MY FAVORITE] Double-click any word to highlight it, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to highlight all instances of it! Use the buttons in the find bar in the top-right (also shown circled below) to choose "Case sensitive search" and/or "Match whole word" as desired too. You can also choose "Regular expression search". Here you can see 8 instances of `_currentChannel_i` all highlighted in blue, including some in the comments! I use love this feature and use it all the time! Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> blue highlighting. [image]
2. [See here for links to my full setup documentation](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/eclipse).

### 2. Sublime Text 3 and 4.

1. From here, if I'm doing some fancy multi-cursor editing, I like to right-click the screen and go to "EasyShell" --> "Open with default Application" to open up this same file in Sublime Text 3 or 4. [image]
2. In Sublime Text 3 and 4, you simply double-click any word to highlight all instances. That looks like this. Here, I have double-clicked `_currentChannel_i`, and you can see 9 instances of it highlighted/boxed, *including* in the comments. Simply click away *anywhere* to undo this selection. [image]
3. Note that you can also highlight a word and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> repeatedly to highlight instances of it, one-at-a-time, each with a new cursor. This is handy when editing all instances of a variable in a single file all at once, for quick-editing/refactoring, rather than using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> Find and Replace tool.

### 3. Microsoft Visual Studio Code (VSCode)

1. This one is super easy too! Just double-click any word to highlight all instances of it--same as Sublime Text 3 and 4. Click away *anywhere* to undo this selection. Here, I have double-clicked `_currentChannel_i`, and you can see 9 instances of it highlighted, *including* in the comments. [image]

### So, which editor to use?

Well, Sublime Text is the lightest, by far, but lacks a good indexer and function view/explorer. It has advanced, modern features like multi-cursor mode. It is made by one lone and very-talented developer, so if you use it, please go buy a license to support his work. That's his livelihood.

Eclipse is the heaviest, by far, but lacks modern features like multi-cursor mode. It is the oldest of the 3, by far, and has a world-class indexer. Since it is the oldest ([first released in 2001](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software))) and FOSS, it is widespread and is used as the base for many other professional editors and microcontroller development platforms, such as the STM32CubeIDE, and the Arduino Professional IDE, both of which are Eclipse-based. For that reason alone, it is worth learning.

Microsoft VSCode is the newest ([first released in 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)), and is more light-weight than Eclipse and more-advanced and feature-rich than Sublime Text. Since it came after the other 2 editors, it was able to borrow ideas from Sublime Text (I'm supposing), such as multi-cursor mode, which is ingenious. Therefore, it contains that feature (see here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_multiple-selections-multicursor), as well as a powerful indexer (which I can't comment on since I haven't used it), and an "OUTLINE" view in the left-hand pane to view a list of functions, definitions, etc., like I can see in the "Outline" view in Eclipse in the right-hand pane. Since it is backed by Microsoft, it is arguably the best-supported of the 3.

Since I am most-familiar with Eclipse, I prefer it in conjunction with Sublime Text. **If you are brand-new to these editors, however, I recommend you just start with Microsoft VSCode and go from there.** Optionally, try out my Eclipse installation and configuration instructions above if you ever find yourself needing or wanting to use Eclipse directly, or STM32CubeIDE or the Arduino Pro IDE.

Comment: This is a recommendation question, and so while there is some interesting information in your answer, the question should be closed, not answered.

Answer (score 0):

There's Geany, but I don't know if it does that.

You could customize gedit to do much of what you want:
http://grigio.org/pimp_my_gedit_was_textmate_linux

If you can't get what you want, you could install Notepad++ with WINE. Try something like [this](http://bur.st/~gunny/winehowto.html).

Answer (score -1):

In **Linux Mint 19 Tara**

Install `geany-plugin-automark`, then start geany, go to

> Menu -> Tools -> Plugin Manager and Enable/check Auto-mark