# change default editor (core.editor) to notepad over SSH

Tags: git, ssh

I ssh from a windows machine to a unix one. When I do a git commit, git always launch Vi on the remote machine so that I could type the commit message.

Is it possible to change the default editor to notepad on the windows client machine ?

Comment: If you want to use a Windows editor you're going to need to install `git` on your Windows host.  You can get `git` for Windows [here](http://git-scm.com/download/win).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I have X-Win32 installed on my PC so I installed SublimeText 2 into the unix machine and adjusted the $PATH then ran `git config --global core.editor sublimetext`

Now 
`$ git commit` will launch SublimeText

also 
`$ sublimetext filename.txt` works as well

Comment: I could still not run notepad, or any other app. but at least I could have something nicer than VI with which I am not so familiar.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to launch a GUI program in Windows over a typical ssh session. If you would like to switch the default editor to a different terminal editor such as nano, you can do that with:

```
git config --global core.editor "nano"
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257519/how-to-change-the-default-editor-for-git)