# Git commit -a opens GNU nano 2.2.6 How should I change it to open Vim instead?

Tags: git, vim, editor, gnu, nano

I  am trying to add a commit message to my changes using

```
git commit -a
```

OR just plain

```
git commit
```

this somehow opens GNU Nano 2.2.6 editor and I am not at all comfortable with it. So the question is :

> How can I modify my settings so that it always opens with VIM ?

What I already have done is inserting following line in my ~/.bash_profile

```
set EDITOR = vim
```

Please help !

Comment: try `export EDITOR=vim`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make git use the editor of my choice for commits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can set it from the command line or in your `.gitconfig`

```
git config --global core.editor vim
```

Answer (score 3):

To make Vim the default editor for Git only, see HST's answer. However, you probably want to have Vim as the default for *all* applications.

That can be done by

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

in your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`. The key is the `export`, otherwise the setting won't inherit to launched processes, like Git is.