# Git + Sublime Text 2 Automatic Merge 'mate -w' issue

Tags: git, github, merge, sublimetext2, branching-and-merging

I am trying to merge a git branch recursively into another git branch. In the past when it was a recursive merge and an automatic merge was successfully executed it would not require a manual commit, but now it gives me the following error:

> mate -w: mate: command not found error: There was a problem with the
>   editor 'mate -w'. Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete
>   the merge.

Before this error started happening it would just automatically commit the merge, without me having to manually commit it. There are not any conflicts at all that I can see. I am using Sublime Text 2 as my text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mate` is the command-line utility for [TextMate](http://www.macromates.com) (an editor for OS X that influenced Sublime Text in many ways) in the same way that `subl` is the command-line utility for Sublime. Somehow (perhaps in your `.gitconfig`?) it got set up as your default editor, and `git` is trying to open it to compose a commit message. Run through your settings (you may also want to check `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.profile`, or other files associated with your particular shell), see where `mate -w` got defined as your `EDITOR`, and change it to to `subl -w`, assuming you've [installed it correctly](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html).

Comment: this makes a lot of sense, because when it would work properly textmate would open and display a message to me saying something about the automatic merge. it no longer does this....

Comment: This seems to have worked for me I think: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15148805/1493749 Thanks for your help!!