# When saving Git message from Vim: e32 No File Name

Tags: git, bash, vim

When saving a new commit message with `git commit -a`, or editing an existing message with `git commit --amend`, Vim seems to be failing to load the proper Git file, and is throwing "e32 No File Name" upon save.

Specifically with editing existing commits via `git commit --amend`, it is not loading the message, but rather displaying the "Vim - Vi Improved" screen. I can proceed to enter a message, and save, then when I check the `git log` I can see the original message, along with some unicode and erroneous characters:

```
commit 07aa5029e376

Original message

<U+0080>ý5:q
```

Comment: What file name does vim think it is working on in this case? What command is running (check `ps`?)?

Comment: @EtanReisner looks like it is writing to `project/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` does that seem right?

Comment: Assuming the filename is `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` then that sounds right. What's the working directory? And that fails to load the current commit contents with `--amend`?

Comment: The directory is just in `~/code` so nothing out of the ordinary there. And yes that is correct, it fails to load the content of the commit.

Comment: Can you try to do following: GIT_EDITOR=anyothereditor git commit --amend

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem and couldn't get it solved anywhere. However, after trying the answer of this post: [How do I make Git use the editor of my choice for commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits), it just worked like intended with no file or utf-error anymore:

> Set the GIT_EDITOR environment variable: export GIT_EDITOR=vim

Thats it. Hope this solves your problem as well.