# Formatting GitHub commit messages from shell

Tags: github, markdown

I just read [Writing good commit messages](https://github.com/erlang/otp/wiki/Writing-good-commit-messages) and liked it a lot. The problem is, I prefer the command line (plain ole' `git`).

- How can I add newlines and tabs to commit messages, so as to have a "summary line" and message body (which may consist of several paragraphs)?
- Does GitHub support markdown in their commit messages? After reading ["Shiny new commit styles"](https://github.com/blog/926-shiny-new-commit-styles) this doesn't seem possible

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`git` automatically spawns your preferred `$EDITOR` to prompt for a commit message when you run `git commit`. So it may be as simple as leaving `-m` off of your `git commit` command

If git launches the wrong editor, or fails to launch an editor, try setting the `EDITOR` environment variable to your preferred editor:

```
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
```

Or, to only change the editor used by git, you can set `core.editor`

```
git config --global core.editor /usr/bin/vim
```

Using an editor to compose a commit message this way has a couple of further advantages. Git populates the file you are editing with a summary of the files that were changed in the commit, which should help you write a better commit message. Also, vim (and other editors) support basic syntax highlighting for this kind of file, making it even easier.

Comment: and in Vim you can navigate to the source by placing the cursor on the filename and typing `gf`

Answer (score 5):

1. For newline, just hit enter inside quotes, like this: `git commit -m "Some headline <hit enter>`. Also you can use [your text editor to write commit messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits).
2. Unfortunately no, e.g. [this commit with markdown](https://github.com/symfony/FrameworkBundle/commit/ed7ae975dec40102582b66d45bd23caaa498beba) for example.

Comment: It's worth noting that if a commit on GitHub with Markdown formatting (like the one you've linked to) is submitted as a pull request, the text of the commit message is used as the PR's text, which does render GitHub-Flavored-Markdown.  Also, there are a couple of Git clients (not-GitHub-specific) here & there that'll render Markdown commit messages.  _I personally write all my commit messages in Markdown— since a couple `**`s or a few lines starting with `* ` can go a long way to convey meaning.  And MD (by design) never looks too grody when displayed as plaintext._

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson : BitBucket also uses the commit message to prefill the PR message.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a git commit, you can use -m multiple times and it will create multiple paragraphs.

To quote the [man page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/git-commit.1)

> -m <msg>, --message=<msg>
>
> Use the given  as the commit message. If multiple -m options are given, their values are concatenated as separate paragraphs

Also, as mentioned before, if you leave out the -m option, then git will open an editor (set with a command like `git config --global core.editor /usr/bin/vim`) in which you can type your commit message.

Answer (score 0):

I'll refer to the first line in the commit as "title", and the following paragraph(s) as "summary" (just like in the [OTP repo wiki](https://github.com/erlang/otp/wiki/Writing-good-commit-messages)).

You can run the following command if you desire to use the CLI to commit your changes:

```bash
git commit -m "Fix feature" -m "Includes foo and bar."
```

`"Fix feature"` will be the commit title and `"Includes foo and bar."` will be the commit summary, which can be multiple paragraphs long. On the GitHub UI, the title is always visible but the summary is hidden behind a small [ellipsis](https://github.com/erlang/otp/pull/7720/commits/bb12bb72f4f2b0075961970f91d62825fd90bafa) button.

If you rather go the visual route, like has been explained above, you can set your preferred editor to edit your commits, anything from Vim to VSCode or even Notepad.

Additionally, if you're already in VSCode, you can use the integrated Source Control Tab and accomplish the exact same behaviour as above. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to open the panel, and in the message textbox enter your commit title. In other to add your commit summary, enter two blank lines and write as many paragraphs as you desire. It should look something like this:

```
Fix feature

Includes foo and bar.
```

The great thing about VSCode is that it'll tell you the max number of characters that are available in the title (50). If you go past this number, the rest of the title will get truncated into the summary (i.e. inside the ellipsis) like I'm sure you have seen happen during a squash and merge.

> PS: I've been inadvertently following the OTP guidelines despite never having come across that repo because I was very meticulous about how to format my commit messages during my first internship 3 years ago. I'm glad I stuck to this formatting because it has forced me to write meaningful commit messages and/or split one commit into several smaller commits with more specific features/fixes. Even if you do not want to be so perfect with your commits, I still encourage you to provide meaningful messages so future you can look at a PR and know exactly when a specific change was committed