# "code ." is not working in on the command line for Visual Studio Code on OS X/Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

The command `code .` doesn't work in [this manual](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs).

All the other steps before that worked. How can I call the Visual Studio Code in an OS X terminal?

```
pwd
```

> /Users/mona/nodejs/myExpressApp

```
code .
```

> -bash: code: command not found

---

I ended up opening it from within Visual Code Studio by changing the workspace, but why won't that command `code .` part work?

[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YereIjEJF7s

Comment: I reinstalled homebrew from scratch in arm64/m1 environment, and /usr/local is no longer in PATH. It's /opt/homebrew now

Comment: if you have install vscode-insider version on mac m1 than you need to run `code-insiderr .`

Comment: it should be `code-insiders .`

Answer (score 3370, accepted):

#### 1. Make sure you drag the Visual Studio Code application into the *Applications* folder

*Otherwise (as noted in the comments), you'll have to go through this process again after a reboot.*

> For example, sometimes the VSCode application might be in your `downloads` folder, so make sure to move it out of there.

---

#### 2. Next, open Visual Studio Code

Open the **Command Palette** via <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and type `shell command` to find the Shell Command:

Use the Uninstall 'code' command in the PATH command before the *"Install 'code' command in PATH"* command.

[image: ![Command Palette]

> After executing the command, restart the terminal for the new $PATH
> value to take effect. You'll be able to simply type 'code .' in any
> folder to start editing files in that folder. The "." Simply means "current directory"

(Source: [Visual Studio Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line))

---

**Remember to Restart your machine afterwards**

**Note:** If you're running a build based off the [OSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software) repository, you will need to run `code-oss .` ([Dzeimsas Zvirblis' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955500/code-is-not-working-in-on-the-command-line-for-visual-studio-code-on-os-x-ma#comment112190379_39604469))

---

#### EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/local/bin/code'

If you see this EACCES error, just run the "Uninstall 'code' command from PATH, *then* the 'install' it again, and you'll be all set!

Comment: this does work, but after reboot I have to do it again.

Comment: It looks like the `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH` in VSCode just creates a symlink in `/usr/local/bin/` now

Comment: Make sure you drag Visual Studio Code.app into the Applications folder.  Otherwise, as @uloco said, you'll have to go through this process again after reboot.

Comment: I don't have shell command in Command Palette. (running on Linux Mint). any other ideas?

Comment: @uloco You really shouldn't have to reboot. Just open a new instance of terminal and you should have the environment variable set.

Comment: even after dragging vscode into Applications, I've to do it every time I restart.

Comment: **NOTE:** If you're running a build based off the `OSS` repository... You will need to run `code-oss .`

Comment: Even in late 2020 I had this problem, and the suggestion of moving to Applications folder fixed it for me. The other thing I had to do was to get rid of the VSCode shortcut I had on on the dock b/c it was pointing to where I previously downloaded (~/Downloads/).

Comment: I have installed vscode editor. It is not displaying in "Applications" then what should I do so that "code ." command open my project in visual studio code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Drag the VSCode appplication into your Applications folder, then you should be all set! @Kamlesh

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31722357/10329023 solved my issue. Now it works like charm :)

Comment: I run `vscode` on windows. The parameters like `--version` do not work. In windows it starts a new instance, in `wsl` the autocomplete like `--ver..sion` works but it starts `Installing VS Code Server` or `updating` it.

Comment: this is the correct answer. Works for this mac system without having to close the terminal. For what its worth.

Comment: DO NOT FORGET the "reboot"~!!! It did not work until I reboot my computer~!! lost 4 hours of my day

Comment: Can confirm this worked!  I didn't realize vs code wasn't in my applications folder and was confused why the command wasn't working when it had been the previous day.

Comment: With Mac M1 chip you also have to uninstall it first

Comment: This solution is working in MaCOS Ventura

Comment: This worked for me, but weirdly when I did `echo $PATH` it shows `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` which seems unrelated to VS Code.

Comment: in mac if your wondering what default shell you have zsh or bash just go to your terminal at the top of it there it was.

Comment: I just installed the 'Shell Command' as instructed in point 2 and everything is working, even I didn't restart my macbook!!! N.B: I checked my VS Code that it was already in Application folder.

Comment: Thanks @JasonGalvin - That was the one missing piece I've had for almost an entire year now. VSCode was in my Downloads folder so I had to redo this set of commands each session and it would never stick. After moving VSCode to the Applications folder it works every time!

Comment: On newer versions of Mac (Ventura?), the VScode 'Add to Path' option doesn't work. You get this error: https://i.imgur.com/oP3mxmp.png "EACCES: permission denied"

Comment: Requiring a reboot is silly, like we were on Windows or something. Could you please indicate what exactly needs to be restarted in order to avoid a reboot? In the meantime, `alias code=/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code` works here.

Comment: yes, if it's not in the Application folder, it seems to need a reboot strangely enough!  @tripleee

Comment: Merely restarting your Terminal should be sufficient, and even that is unnecessary if you know how to update the settings of your running shell. My question is what else, if anything, needs to be restarted if you want to avoid a reboot. I do know VS Code wants to install some "helper" system extensions.

Comment: MacOS is better than windows they say...

Answer (score 322):

If you want to add it permanently:

Add this to your `~/.bash_profile`, or to `~/.zshrc` if you are running [macOS v10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina) or later. (To add,  `cd ~` and `vim ~/.bash_profile` in terminal)

```bash
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
```

This assumes that you have VS Code in `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app`; if you have it installed in a different location ... probably move it to Applications (or modify the code to point to your custom location).

Elaborating the process to add to the file:

1. Open terminal and go to base directory using `cd ~`
2. Then, `vim ~/.bash_profile` inorder to edit the file
3. Press `i` for making an insertion and paste the string `export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"` at the end
4. Save and close using `:wq`
5. Once this is done, paste `source ~/.zshrc`

Source: *[Visual Studio Code on macOS](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac)*

Comment: Look like now code is under /usr/local/bin, so it might be better to update the answer :)

Comment: worked for me, please specify 2 more points here, you need to write the PATH variable by `vim ~/.zshrc` and run `source ~/.zshrc` to reload zsh

Comment: Worked well for me with `~/.zshrc` on Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: This worked for me despite the fact that using the VS Code Install 'code' command in PATH command results in `which code` returning /usr/local/bin`. That was already on my PATH the true location of the executable is where you've installed VS COde.

Comment: Note this only works if Visual Studio Code is actually installed in the `Applications` folder. Mine was sitting in `Downloads`!

Comment: I needed to add a \ before every whitespace character in order for this to work for me `export PATH=”$PATH:/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin”`

Comment: You should really not need the `export`; your shell will already have marked this variable for export a long long time ago.

Comment: @Steezens That doesn't look right. You probably forgot the double quotes around the value. You need to either quote the value or escape the shell metacharacters, but not both. (Zsh is more relaxed than Bash when it comes to _requiring_ quotes, too.)

Comment: This is the right solution in the year 2024.

Answer (score 132):

Go the top of VS and select menu *View* → *Command Palette...*

- [macOS] Open the Command Palette via <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and type `shell command` to
  find the `Shell Command:`
- [Windows] Open the Command Palette via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type `shell command` to
  find the `Shell Command:`

---

Type: *shell command*

[image]
And install.

Comment: This is nearly identical to [Josie Koay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955500/code-is-not-working-in-on-the-command-line-for-visual-studio-code-on-os-x-ma/70098246#70098246).

Comment: Is "shell command" literal or not? It doesn't seem to do anything—"No matching commands" (version 1.66 of Visual Studio Code. On Linux, though). Is it dependent on some extension being installed? What version of Visual Studio Code was it tried on?

Comment: If someone gets the error as "EACCES: permission denied", then please follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69219632/885627

Uninstall the code command from PATH in VS Code and reinstall it. Open the command palette in VS Code using cmd + shift + p. Search "uninstall 'code'" and select the first option to uninstall. Once uninstalled, "install 'code'" for installing. That should fix it.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 77):

Open the [~/.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) file using [vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) or [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29):

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

Enter the following by pressing `i` to insert:

```
code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;}
```

Save and exit the file using `Esc` +  `:wq`

Reflect the settings in ~/.bashrc using the following command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: this worked for me, I was getting an error "cannot execute binary file" after my path probably got messed somehow - but now it won't open any files if i do code filename, just opens an empty window of VS code

Comment: Does this still work? The default shell changed to [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) in [macOS v10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina).

Comment: The file you need to modify is different if you are using Zsh. You'll want to put this into your `.zprofile` instead, and then of course `source` that file instead (or just paste the same snippet at your terminal prompt; there is no specific requirement to load it from your `.zprofile` and there are situations where you want to avoid sourcing it a second time).

Comment: Strictly speaking you want `"$@"`, not `$*`. The latter will work incorrectly when you try to edit files whose names contain spaces, etc.

Answer (score 58):

Use:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/code
```

Open Visual Studio Code, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

[image]

And write command `install code` and you will get a popup. Then follow the instruction and *done*!

Comment: this is just temporary solution, because after reboot need to do it again.

Comment: does not work for mac os monterey

Comment: Okay, let me update a permanent solution for any mac os version.

Comment: This seems like a solution for a very specific scenario which will be **exactly wrong** in many others.

Answer (score 47):

Steps to follow:

1. Open the Visual Studio Code application, and type <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and type the command
   '**install code**'. Then enter it.
2. You will see the below message in Visual Studio Application: **shell command '
   code' successfully installed in PATH.**
3. Now, jump to the [iTerm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITerm2) CLI and type ***code .***
4. Then you will be able to redirect to Visual Studio Code for any code change/view.

Comment: this worked for me. thanks! For mac users, make sure vs code is in the applications folder.

Comment: Show us instead of telling us. I'm a new user and I don't even now where the applications folder is, and no idea of to "make sure".

Comment: `No matching commands` for me.

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz A picture is much more ambiguous than an explanation. Your applications folder is named `/Applications` (though if you have a localized MacOS it might be displayed in your own language. Even then, this path should work e.g. in Finder).

Comment: @tripleee You are wrong. An explanation won't convince everybody. An engineer can't sit in a meeting and explain why his machine works or doesn't. It won't get through. If you have landed on Mars and completed the mission, a picture will be a lot more convincing than a guy sitting in a meeting and telling stories. Don't believe me. Try it yourself. Sit in a meeting and try to explain why hardware or software works or doesn't work, especially to a non-expert. Show a picture of a car-crash it it immediately communicates everything.

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz You are missing a crucial point. A machine-readable standard path works on any system, whereas a picture of the Finder with English labels will leave you guessing what to look for if your system is set up for Turkish or Japanese. (Granted, the A-like icon will still be the same I imagine.)

Answer (score 45):

For those of you that run [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) with [iTerm2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITerm2), add this to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```bash
alias code="/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code"
```

Comment: Thanks, zsh user here too, this was just what I needed, though my path was a little different in order to get it to work:
alias code="/Applications/VisualStudioCode.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code"

Comment: It didn't work for me. Now it doesn't even recognise code anymore

Comment: @AMMA I would think it has a lot to do with where you installed your VSCode.

Comment: Z shell [became the default shell with macOS v10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina#Removed_or_changed_components) (Catalina)—released about half a year after this answer.

Comment: Been very irritated having to reinstall it every time I restart my macbook THIS answer fixed it! Incase it doesn't work for you you can also try to change the path to /usr/local/bin/code

Answer (score 43):

On my Mac I got it working:

Add to file *[.bash_profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)*:

```bash
code() {
   open -a Visual\ Studio\ Code.app $1
}
```

Save and in the terminal do `source .bash_profile`.

Then in the terminal, `code index.html` (or whatever) will open that file in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: This also worked in .zprofile

Comment: This breaks when `$1` contains spaces or other shell metacharacters. The minimal fix is to use `"$1"` instead; but you probably want `"$@"` which allows you to specify more than one argument. Also, perhaps mention that this requires `Visual Studio Code.app` to be in your `/Applications` folder.

Answer (score 30):

#### Setup code. In just one second

Just follow one simple command with the following steps:

1. Open the Visual Studio Code application
2. <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
3. Type command 'install code'. Then enter it.

Boom, it’s *done*.

Now use the command `Code .` where you want to use it.

Comment: I don't think "`Code .`" will work for the question here (Mac). It *may* work on a Windows system. On a Linux system I get "`Command 'Code' not found`".

Answer (score 29):

Here are the steps which I followed to make it work on Mac:

Install the "Shell" extension from Visual Studio Code:

[image]

Restart Visual Studio Code.

Press <kbd>F1</kbd> when Visual Studio Code is opened.

Type "Shell" and select the following option:
Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command:

[image]

That will give you the following message:
Shell command 'code' successfully installed in PATH.

[image]

Running the "which code" command will give you a proof the 'code' command is working now:

[image]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (it is not only about questions), and take the appropriate action. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `which` is standard on MacOS, but there is still no reason to prefer `which` over the POSIX alternative `command -v`

Answer (score 28):

For Mac OS X, there are three ways you can enable `code .` to open the current folder in Visual Studio Code.

#### For a fresh installation

**Install Visual Studio Code through Homebrew**

There is a way to install Visual Studio Code through Brew-Cask.

1. First, install [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) from [here](https://brew.sh/).
2. Now run the following command, and it will install the latest Visual Studio Code on your Mac.

   ```
   brew cask install visual-studio-code
   ```

The above command should install Visual Studio Code and also set up the command-line calling of Visual Studio Code.

If the above steps don't work then you can do it manually. By following Microsoft Visual Studio Code documentation given [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac).

#### If Visual Studio Code  is already installed

If Visual Studio Code  is already installed then you don't have to reinstall it. You can follow any of the below two options.

**Option 1: Update PATH in the Bash profile**

Update your favorite Bash profile, such as `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` by exporting the `app/bin` path of the Visual Studio Code  application. You can add the below `export` command to your favorite Bash profile.

`export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"`

**Option 2: Using the Visual Studio Code Command Palette**

We can run a shell command in the Visual Studio Code Command Palette too. To do so, we need to open the ***Command Palette*** via (⇧⌘P) and type "shell command" to find the shell command named as:

`Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH`

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the above shell command.

[image]

That's it.

Answer (score 25):

Please follow below steps

1. Open VSCode
2. Press `command + p`.
3. Type `>shell command` in the input box at the top.
4. A dropdown will come, now select `install code command in PATH` option.

[image]

Comment: I do not have to reload the vscode application in order to use the `code` command. This fully works for me.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This works for me. However, I need to do it every day to use the code command in the terminal.
Please let me know if there is any solution for the same.

Answer (score 15):

I tried this by following [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac) and it works for me:

1. Launch Visual Studio Code
2. Open the *Command Palette* (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) and type 'shell command' to find

   Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command

   [image]
3. Restart terminal

Comment: How is this different from [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955500/code-is-not-working-in-on-the-command-line-for-visual-studio-code-on-os-x-ma/39604469#39604469)?

Answer (score 14):

See *[Setting up Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/setup-overview)*

Tip: If you want to run Visual Studio Code from the terminal, append the following to your [.bashrc file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) file:

```
code () {
if [[ $# = 0 ]]
then
    open -a "Visual Studio Code"
else
    [[ $1 = /* ]] && F="$1" || F="$PWD/${1#./}"
    open -a "Visual Studio Code" --args "$F"
fi
}
```

Then `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Yes. The `source ~/.bashrc` is missing from the official docs.

Comment: This only allows you to pass in a single argument, and it cannot be an option. I don't see that the PWD mogrification would be necessary or useful; `open -a` already knows which directory you are in.

Answer (score 14):

This works for me:

```
sudo ln -fs "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code" /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: *Why* does it work? What is the gist of it? An explanation would be in order. From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62679074/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: I can't speak for OP, but a version of this worked for me because a `ls -lah /usr/local/bin` showed that `code` was in there and linked to a long directory path...that didn't exist. So I just deleted it and made a new link to the `/Application` folder path that *did* exist. Now when the shell looks for code in `/usr/local/bin`, it find it, and not a broken link.

Comment: If you use windows, you can use `sudo ln -s "/mnt/c/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code" /us r/bin/code.` * xxx means PC User

Comment: Note that `-f` tells `ln` to unceremoniously replace any existing link without notifying you. Perhaps look before you jump.

Answer (score 12):

It was quite simple to follow the documentation to install 'code' to PATH, but it didn't work.

I *simply* uninstalled it first and then installed it again.

Open the Command Palette (⇧⌘P)

```
Shell Command: Uninstall 'code' command in PATH command.
```

Then install it again.

```
Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command.
```

Restart your terminal to have the new PATH included.

Answer (score 7):

For that to work, there needs to be an executable named 'code' in your Bash path, which some installers add for you, but this one apparently did not.

The best way to do this could be to add a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) to the Visual Studio Code application in your `/usr/local/bin` folder. You can do this by using a command like the following in your terminal.

```
ln -s "/Path/To/Visual Studio Code" "/usr/local/bin/code"
```

You will likely need to put `sudo` in front of that to have the permissions for it to complete successfully.

Comment: "/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron" should be the target

Comment: If you use windows, you can use `sudo ln -s "/mnt/c/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code" /us
r/bin/code`. 
* xxx means PC User

Comment: The above comment may be obsolete. `Electron` runs some parts, but as of 2024, the real thing is in `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code` (and also, you want _either_ double quotes around the value, or escape the spaces with a backslash; but not both).

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Visual Studio Code [*Insiders* build](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/):

```
code-insiders .
```

With regular Visual Studio Code:

```
code .
```

Answer (score 7):

[image: VSCodium]

If you came here from search engine and are a free/open source user like me looking for [VSCodium](https://vscodium.com/) (Free/Libre Open Source of VSCode) instead of Microsoft spyware VSCode, then here is a little change for you.

In VSCodium binary executable `code` is called `codium`.

So, when you open the Command Line Terminal via <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type in `shell command` to find the `codium`.

You should be able to open VSCodium using:

`codium .`

Answer (score 4):

I foolishly deleted my `/usr/local/bin/code` symbolic link and did not know the correct path. A [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) reinstall recreated it:

```
brew cask reinstall visual-studio-code
```

The path turned out to be:

```
/usr/local/bin/code ->
'/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code'
```

Comment: Might be worth updating this answer for newer versions of brew, otherwise you'll get this error: `Error: `brew cask` is no longer a `brew` command. Use `brew <command> --cask` instead.`

Answer (score 3):

**Mac OS X**

1. Download Visual Studio Code for Mac OS X.
2. Double-click *onVSCode-osx.zip* to expand the contents.
3. Drag Visual Studio Code.app to the Applications folder, making it available in the Launchpad.
4. Add Visual Studio Code to your Dock by right-clicking on the icon and choosing *Options, Keep in Dock*.

Tip: If you want to run Visual Studio Code from the terminal, append the following to your ~/[.bash_profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) file (~/.zshrc in case you use [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (executable `zsh`)).

```
code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;}
```

Now, you can simply type `code .` in any folder to start editing files in that folder.

Comment: `$*` isn't really correct; you want `"$@"`. This seems like roughly a duplicate of Mick dK's answer from 2015.

Answer (score 2):

If this is happening on [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) or [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), it is likely because you installed Visual Studio Code through the software manager. This will cause other problems during debugging. Instead install it using the .deb file on the Visual Studio Code website.

If you really want to use the software manager, the solution below still works:

Use `find / -name code 2> /dev/null` to find the path to the Visual Studio Code binary file. It should end in `/extra/vscode/bin/code`

If you're using the Linux Mint software manager, you might only find paths with a ridiculously long name in the middle like this:

".../stable/7a22830d9e8fbbdc9627e43e072005eef66c14d2a4dd19992427ef4de060186a/..."

Just replace the long part with "/active/"

Once you have it, create a symbolic link:

`ln -s path_you_found/extra/vscode/bin/code /usr/local/bin/code`

If you don't have the rights, or only want it to be accessible for yourself, simply add this line to your [.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) or .zshrc file:

`export PATH="$PATH:path_you_found/extra/vscode/bin/`

Note that I removed the 'code' filename at the end.

Comment: Yes, but the question was about OS X/macOS.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows and facing the same problem, have a look at Inazense's answer, *[Visual Studio Code - "Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528373/visual-studio-code-shell-command-install-code-command-in-path-command/52869803#52869803)*.

In Visual Studio Code I was not able to find **“Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command.”** so I had to do this manually.

1. Open *Environment Variables* (*System* → *Advanced system settings* → *Advanced* tab → *Environment variables*). In system variables, click on *Path* and click <kbd>Edit</kbd> and add a new path named:

> "C:\Users\Your_Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin"

Now you are done! Restart the command prompt and try again.

Comment: Yes, but the question is about OS X/macOS.

Answer (score 1):

If you have trouble using the [**Command Palette** solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39604469/4693496), you can manually add Visual Studio Code to the `$PATH` environment variable when your terminal starts:

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.bash_profile
# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio
Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative to a command line solution:**

Recently I was playing with *services* in Mac OS X. I added a service to a folder or file so that I can open that folder or file in Visual Studio Code. I think this could be an alternative to using the 'code .' command if you are using the [Finder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_(software)) app.

Here are the steps:

- Open Automator App from Application (or you can use Spotlight).
- Click on the <kbd>New Document</kbd> button to create a new script.
- Choose 'Service' as a new type of document.
- Select 'files and folders' in 'Service receives selected' dropdown.
- Search for 'Open Finder Items' action item.
- Drag that action item to the workflow area.
- Select the 'Visual Studio Code.app' application in the action 'Open with' dropdown.
- Press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save the service. It will ask a name of service. Give it a name. I gave 'Open with Visual Studio Code'. Close the Automator app. Check the image below for more information.

  [image]

Verify:

- Open the Finder app.
- Right-click on any folder.
- In the context menu, look for 'Open with Visual Studio Code' menu option.
- Click on the 'Open with Visual Studio Code' menu option.
- The folder should get open in the Visual Studio Code application. Check image below for more information.

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I had to add Visual Studio Code to my applications folder. It worked without editing a file.

1. Open the *Applications* folder

   [image]
2. Search for Visual Studio Code in your search

   [image]
3. Drag Visual Studio Code to the *Applications* folder

   [image]

This will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure VS Code is installed and moved to Application section**

**Open VS Code**

**Open the Command Palette (⇧⌘P)**

```
Shell Command: Uninstall 'code' command in PATH command.
```

**Then install it again.**

```
Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command.
```

**Restart Terminal (Better OS)**

Answer (score 0):

Define the path of the Visual Studio Code in your [~/.bash_profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) file as follows:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the *"Install add `code`"* command to PATH with Visual Studio Code's command panel, but it's disabled after restarting Bash. If you want it be consolidated, just create a `code` file in your PATH;
I create a `code` file in `usr/local/bin` and add

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function realpath() { python -c "import os,sys;print(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[1]))" "$0"; }
CONTENTS="/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents"
ELECTRON="$CONTENTS/MacOS/Electron"
CLI="$CONTENTS/Resources/app/out/cli.js"
ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 "$ELECTRON" "$CLI" "$@"
exit $?
```

Just replace this *CONTENTS* with your Visual Studio Code's installed path. And don't forget make it executable with `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/code`.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it looks obsolete. As of 2024, `"/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code" "$@"` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Note: with [Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) for Visual Studio Code 1.58 (June 2021), you have [Microsoft/Visual Studio Code issue 126702](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/126702) (on Windows, but also Mac).

> `code-insiders .` is not opening the current directory. It opens the path to code insiders instead.

This has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS, search for the Visual Studio Code application. For example, it was in my *Downloads* section.

Now copy that to the *Applications* folder and then run the following commands.

- Open terminal and type `vi ~/.zshrc`
- Add this line at the end (if not empty) `export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"`
- Press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> (in short, quit the terminal)
- Again open up the terminal and go to the Git code folders

You are all sorted now.

Comment: What is the *"Downloads section"*? The web browser's download folder? Or something Mac-specific?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Presumably they downloaded the binary in their browser and so it was in their `~/Downloads` folder (not "section").

Answer (score 0):

This is what has worked out for me!

1. **Remove** existing `code` command from $PATH using Visual Studio Code.[image: Using Visual Studio Code to remove "code" command from PATH]

2. **Move into** `/etc/paths.d` and **create a new file** named `code` into it.

   ```
    cd /etc/paths.d && touch code
   ```
3. **Edit the content** of `code` as following:

   ```
   /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin
   ```
4. **Restart** your terminal, and you can use your `code` command as usual.

Answer (score -1):

**It might be possible** that you have not installed Visual Studio Code in your system. So, please install it first. the command is here -

```
sudo snap install --classic code
```

Details are available [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux).

Comment: The vast majority of MacOS users do not have `snap`. This might work for Ubuntu (though "work" and "snap" generally don't occur in the same sentence, in my brief experience).

Answer (score -1):

In [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa):

```
# Symbolic link the bin command to /usr/bin
rm -f /usr/bin/code
ln -s /usr/share/code/bin/code /usr/bin/code
```

Comment: What do you mean by "bin command"? E.g., is "bin" literal?

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68257584/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: You absolutely should not manipulate `/usr/bin` or `/usr/share` yourself; these directories are owned and controlled by your OS. It is unclear why you expect `/usr/share/code` to contain the app in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

This is something that worked for me:

`export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"`

run this on command shell and then VS can be opened from command line

Comment: This duplicates nullify's answer from 2017.

Answer (score -1):

In my case:

1. Move vscode to application
2. Try run: `sudo chown -R yourUsername /usr/local/bin` in terminal
3. Open the Command Palette via `⌘+⇧+P` and type shell command and use the Install 'code' command
4. Restart Mac

Comment: Making yourself the owner of `/usr/local/bin` is *extremely **bad advice.*** Just like you should not run as `root` at all times, you should not make yourself the owner of system resources; then you don't even need to be `root` to wreck everything.

Answer (score -2):

It's simple. Just type this on your terminal. You can use the first or the second command:

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.bash_profile
export PATH="\$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
EOF
```

Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

But, since [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) became the default shell in [macOS Catalina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina), run the following commands to add Visual Studio Code to your path:

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.zprofile
export PATH="\$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
EOF
```

I used the latest command, and it worked for me.

Comment: Why not `echo "...." >> ~/.zprofile` (or the equivalent with `printf`)?

Comment: The part starting with "`cat << EOF >> ~/.bash_profile`"  is an *exact* copy from *[Visual Studio Code on macOS, section "Alternative manual instructions"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line)*, without attribution.