# Mac OSx and VS Code: getting `LSGetApplicationForInfo() failed with error` when starting from terminal

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I installed VS Code and run the `Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH` as per documentation (and as found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39604469))

At first it was working, but after a reboot (I suppose) I couldn't get code started from a terminal (which is pretty useful).

This is the error I get:

`LSGetApplicationForInfo() failed with error -10814 while trying to determine the application with bundle identifier com.microsoft.VSCodeInsiders.`

Not sure if helpful: if I type `which code` I get `/usr/local/bin/code`.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution for this is to do the following:

1. Open the terminal
2. Find the path of the OS X app that you're having this problem with
3. Run the following command:
   `mdls -name kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier -r <app-path>`

The bundle name that's returned by this will be the actual name of the bundle (which `com.microsoft.VSCodeInsiders` is *not*.)

You can then open the application by typing `open -b <bundle-name>` with whichever args afterwards.

Hints:
- Your `<app-path>` might contain spaces, in which case you should surround it with " (quotes). 
- The `<app-path>` is the path to the directory that ends in `.app` -- the path of the "icon" you see in the finder for the application. In the terminal, the name of the folder will end with `.app`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution above from marco worked, so to make it more friendly, I've added to my `~/.aliases`

```
alias code='open -b com.microsoft.VSCode'
```

Then, again I can `code .` and open the vscode in my current path.