# Visual Studio command line shortcut doesn't persist after closing the editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've installed the Visual Studio `code` command line shortcut using their package manager:

[image]

However, I find that if I close Visual Studio, the Fish shell doesn't recognize the `code` command anymore:

[image]

In my `/usr/local/bin` (which is in my path), I find that `code` is a link to the following:

```
/u/l/bin> ls -lh *code*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 kurtpeek  admin   167B Aug 13 15:10 code -> /private/var/folders/0p/jfjngh2x19dfyg2dpxnw7f2h0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/CAEB3997-9AD6-458F-8778-37C23B7B4F53/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code
```

It seems that the actual executable is no longer available at this location? In any case, how can I get the `code` command-line shortcut to keep working even after I close Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had forgotten to drag `Visual Studio Code.app` into the `Applications` folder as mentioned in a comment in ["code ." Not working in Command Line for Visual Code Studio on OSX/Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955500/code-not-working-in-command-line-for-visual-code-studio-on-osx-mac).