# VS Code Denied Permission unlink 'usr/local/bin/code'

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I can add the "shell command install 'code' command". Testing it works, but if i close out of the VS Code or after a couple of hours of adding the command it doesn't work. Terminal says "zsh: command not found: code" and on VS when click on the "shell command install code command"  has a "EACCES: permission denied, unlink 'usr/local/bin/code' " pop up. How should i go about this? I'm using a macbook 2020 if that matters

Answer (score 417):

Uninstall the code command from PATH in VS Code and reinstall it.
Open the command palette in VS Code using `cmd + shift + p`. Search `"uninstall 'code'"` and select the first option to uninstall.
Once uninstalled, `"install 'code'"` for installing.
That should fix it.

Comment: I've had to do this again after a while. Sometimes it doesn't get fixed the first time. Sometimes I have to switch directories till it works. Not sure what the cause is

Comment: it worked but what is the cause of this?

Comment: witaf.... why..

Comment: works just fine

Answer (score 71):

This happened to me on Macbook Pro M1 Chip. Basically follow this:

> Simply uninstall the code command from PATH in vscode and reinstalled. i.e open the command pallete, search "uninstall 'code'" and select the first option to uninstall. Do same for installing too. That should fix it.

[Found this solution on github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/129884#issuecomment-895748836)

Comment: I'd suggest restarting Visual Studio code after each step. My VS Code editor didn't seem to update these optons properly until I restarted after each step

Comment: Spent over an hour trying so many suggestions... this worked perfect!

Comment: This was the easy fix for me!  Cheers 

Answer (score 57):

Try run:

```
sudo chown -R yourUsername /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: correct solution

Comment: Ditto, followed the others with no luck. Cheers @GChaves.

Comment: Without running this, I wasn't able to uninstall the code command from PATH and re-install it as suggested by other answers.

Comment: I want to better understand this solution. Is it a security risk to change the permissions from root on this path? Traditionally did this path always require modifying the permissions to run executables installed there? It seems like everything generally installs there, yet, I have to use sudo to actually run anything, unless I chown. This seems odd?

Answer (score 21):

For `Mac` I have run below steps in my terminal and it resolve my issue.
you can also Try:

1. Open terminal.

```bash
sudo chown -R your_user_name /usr/local/bin
```

2. Open visual studio code.
3. use keybord `command` + `shift` + `p`
4. Type the bellow command.
   `install 'code'`
   [Vs Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJH65.png)
5. For test go to terminal and run `code .`

Answer (score 19):

I've run into this a few times on before. Steps I took to that fixed it for me:

1. open vs code and press `cmd + shift + p` to open the command palette
2. search for `uninstall 'code'` and press Enter
3. lastly, search for `install 'code'` and press Enter

Answer (score 17):

This command solves user just for copy paste.

`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/bin`

Comment: but ... why though

Answer (score 11):

What was happening for me in MAC M1 was after uninstalling and installing again, it still was not able to find binary (or looses it after terminal restart). This what worked for me -

1. Open VS Code and press `cmd + shift + p` to open the command palette
2. Search for `uninstall 'code'` and press Enter
3. Search for `install 'code'` and press Enter
4. Add this to your `bashrc` or `zshrc` or `zprofile`(or whatever your shell is). To add this bin to your `$PATH` in shell `export PATH="/usr/local/bin/:$PATH"`

Feel free to try it. Works now, at the time of writing this answer, **might** not work with updates in future if VSCode decides to place this binary somewhere else or Mac updates breaks something else.

Comment: Step 4 of the above is exactly what I needed, as running the "install 'code'" in VS Code won't work if you do not already have the "/usr/local/bin" in your path.  In my case, in my new Mac, I had previously created a very basic .zprofile myself, and the "/usr/local/bin" path was not yet in that zprofile, which explains why VS Code was not retaining the 'code' command.  For the record, ChatGPT just provided the same answer as this one, adding that this path is NECESSARY for the Visual Studio "install 'code'" command to take hold permanently.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue on my mac.
The problem is solved for me with that:

1. Open VSCode
2. Click on File then chose Close Window
3. reopen VSCode (You have to see the welcome page) and `press cmd + shift + p` to open the command palette
4. search for `uninstall 'code'` and press Enter
5. search for `install 'code'` and press Enter

After that i can open from terminal with `code .` from any library.

Answer (score 8):

From a sample size of me and three friends, this is a common problem on M1 MacBooks and Mac Minis. Running the command:

```
sudo chown -R yourUsername /usr/local/bin
```

This resolved the VS issue for me and allowed me to install npm packages globally.

Answer (score 3):

For macOS:

1. Try uninstalling and reinstalling. (command + shift + p) >shell Command: Uninstall 'code' command from Path
2. append the following to your ~/.bash_profile file (~/.zshrc in case you use zsh).

   ```
   code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;}
   ```

Comment: Number 1. was enough. Why is the extra step needed? Is it for future-proofing? Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution with these steps. When I applied these steps and even restarted my Mac, it worked.

1- Open downloads. Copy Vs Code. Paste in finder applications.

2- If you already installed 'code' on Vs Code. (Else jump to next step.)
Use keyboard command + shift + p. Type and select;
Shell command "uninstall".

3- Open terminal and
type

```
sudo chown -R mac_user /usr/local/bin
```

4- Open Vs Code.
Use keyboard command + shift + p. Type and select;
Shell command "install".

5- Now open terminal and try

```
code .
```

I hope it will work for rest of not have solution.

Answer (score 2):

for any `mac` users, you can try

```
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/code
```

That should help. It's important to note that you should be careful using sudo, since you can do a lot of damage in files and folders with it. But in the most dire instances, you should use it, similar to using any kind of `--force` commands, you should not use it often.

Answer (score 2):

For `Mac` users the solution is:

```bash
sudo chown -R your_username /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/bin

I tried this on on macos m3 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error to Install on Windows 11:

- Just deleted folder C:\Users\my-username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
- Also removed VS Code from environment variables

Installed successfully!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem on Mac (none of the above suggested solutions worked for me). I solved it by:

1. deleting VSCode & re-installing it (I unzipped the folder onto my desktop & then physically moved the application (VSCode) into my Applications folder).
2. then I opened VSCode & used cmd + shift + p to select "Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH".
3. I closed the program, & tried code . in the terminal (it worked).
4. I restarted my computer & again ran code . in the terminal & it worked! Cheers!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34710950)

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Comment: I added my answer because I tried all of the above answers & they didn't work so I thought someone else might find my solution useful. I think the previous answers aren't sufficient because they did not work in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

it just like what the error say "you dont have permission"
so just give your user the permission
by use "whoami" to get your current user -> lets say it is ->(mark22)
then use chown comman to make the dir own by the user by the command
sudo chown -R mark22 /usr/local/bin
then open vscode and press command + shift + p (mac)or ctrl + shift + p(linux windows)
and write :  >shell command: install 'code' command in path

Comment: Please try to edit your answer: brake it to sentences, use punctuation, apply code formatting. Please read the 'How to answer' section in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer