# Not able to run Azure functions in VS code in mac?

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-code

I am trying to follow this tutorial to run azure function app using C# using vscode.
But when I click the run button, it shows "You must have the Azure Functions Core Tools installed to debug your local functions." But I have actually installed it in my mac. When I click the install button, it shows errors like follows:
`/bin/bash: func: command not foundThe terminal process "/bin/bash '-c', 'func host start'" failed to launch (exit code: 127).`
[image]

And on the right bottom there is a small window showing:

[image]

`Error exists after running preLaunchTask "host start". View task output for more information.`

But when I use the command `func host start` in my local terminal, it can run smoothly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have tried the same but on Windows(OS) , Below are the workaround to resolve the above issue.

- Created a new *Azure function with HTTP Trigger* using `.net 6`
  [image]
- *Before debugging we have started the Azure storage Emulator/Azurite on local*.

[image]

Or *Alternatively*, We can add `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",` in our `localsettings.json` and tried to debug by using `.net Function`.

[image]

***OUTPUT DETAILS FOR REFERENCE:-***

[image]

***NOTE:-*** *To run function locally based on the given* [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-csharp?tabs=in-process#run-the-function-locally):-

> Click on  `Ctrl -`  (macOS) the `HttpExample` function and choose Execute
> Function Now [image]

Or, *we can add a breakpoint over our* `function.cs` *file and type start debug as shown below* :-

[image]

For more information regarding ***VS CODE on macos configuration*** Please refer this [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955500/code-is-not-working-in-on-the-command-line-for-visual-studio-code-on-os-x-ma?rq=1) discussions .