# How to initialize the bashrc on Git Bash

Tags: linux, command-line, sublimetext3, git-bash

I was trying to set up launching Sublime from the command line and I might make some mistakes. Now I can open my sublime_text.exe on Git Bash by inputting "subl" , which is what I want, but it shows stuff like this because of my mistakes:

[image]

And I know it is because something is wrong with bashrc. When I test bashrc it shows these 3 lines as well:

[image]

I do not want those stuff and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you include the contents of your `bashrc`?

Comment: I just used image urls on those blue words. Please click them 2 and see my screenshots. Thanks. XP

Comment: I saw you screenshots, those are the outputs. But to be able to help you we need to know the contents of bashrc. I suspect there is something wrong there related to `var` and `begin`.

Comment: Oh I fixed that just now. I found ".bashrc" and deleted some stuff that I did not need and those lines were finally gone. Actually, I wrote those words like var and begin into it by accident. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It would be nice if you post an answer, showing what modifications you did to your bashrc. Otherwise, this question has no reason to stay on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your subl alias, make sure to use [unix-like path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32282884/6309):

```
alias subl="/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe"
```

Or (simpler)

```
export PATH="$PATH:/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3"
alias subl=sublime_text.exe
```