# Ctrl C when using Vim for git workflow

Tags: shell, vim, emacs, putty

I am used to using emacs (I know bad habit), and Git opens vim for commit messages.  I enter my commit message and hit ctrl-x, ctrl-c out of habit and it always freezes up the shell (I am using putty).

- Why does it freeze up the whole shell?
- Can I configure ctrl-x, ctrl-c to be the same as :x in vim?
- Can I configure git to use emacs?
- Should I just stop using emacs and get on the vim wagon?

Comment: Consider [making multiple posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) if you want to ask multiple questions. It makes deduplication and rating easier.

Comment: Why not just set EDITOR=emacs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does it freeze up the whole shell?

It doesn't, but it also doesn't quit vim so it could appear that way.

> Can I configure ctrl-x, ctrl-c to be the same as :x in vim?

Yes, but it's a really, really bad solution to this problem.

> Can I configure git to use emacs?

[Yes, easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits). Also, if you had formally [set emacs as your editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432524/how-do-i-find-and-set-my-editor-environment-variable), `git` would already be using it (as would `crontab`, `vipw` and all other commands that invoke editors).

> Should I just stop using emacs and get on the vim wagon?

Not because of this. Just set emacs as your default editor.

Comment: Using it from Putty it does freeze up the entire session.  I can not type anything or get the session to respond in anyway (that I know of)

Comment: @ajon Putty doesn't do that for me. Is it similar to the effect when pressing Ctrl-S?

Comment: You are a genious.  It was actually Ctrl-S that freezes up Vim.  I was in the habit of typing Ctrl-x Ctrl-s Ctrl-x Ctrl-c really quickly to save in emacs.  I didn't realize Ctrl-s locks the screen in vim and Ctrl-q releases it.  THANKS for this tip.  I have been using vim exclusively since yesterday and have learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

(mandatory answer: a note about Magit)

You have your workflow with git within the shell. Fine. Can I suggest to use git from within emacs, with the Magit package ?

http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Magit

http://magit.vc/

Magit allows to do many many stuff with a few keys and an interactive interface. Maybe my favorite one is the interactive rebase. In the shell, I'd type something like (sorry I forgot the precise syntax!)

```
git rebase -i HEAD~~~~
```

right ? Then I replace every "pick" with another keyword.

With magit, I'll call the magit status (`M-x magit-status`, or my custom `S-g`). I'm displayed a nice window from where I can explore the repo and fire actions:

[image: magit status]

I call `ll` to see a short list of commits. I put the cursor on the one I want to rebase from and I either see the menu either type `r`. I'm displayed a little menu with different options. I choose `e` for interactive. I'm displayed the commits with "pick" in front of them and at each one I type `f` to fixup, `r` to reword, etc.

It's so handy, hope you didn't know about it and that you'll like it.