# Git - How to close a prompt opened while merging a remote branch?

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm new to git still learning. I was merging a branch from the remote. But i stuck with this prompt.

I want to know How to edit this?
How to save it?
And most importantly how to close it.?

[image]

I try 'q' to exit , space to 'scroll' but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: This is called vi. Use `:q` or `:wq` to write and quit, or `:q!` to force quit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git bash uses Vi/Vim for modifying commit messages:

- `dd` deletes a line of text
- `i` enters insert mode to enter text.
- `ESC` to exit edit mode.
- `:wq` will write (save) then close.

Here's a [cheat sheet](https://www.fprintf.net/vimCheatSheet.html)

Comment: Well, to be precise Git can use various editors not only Vi/Vim. This is [configurable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits)

Comment: @JustMe Well there's something I actually wasn't aware of. Thanks for the tip.