# Git Commands at a Glance

Tags: git, command-line, version-control, command, git-bash

I need a full git command and function sheet.  I've found the git book, which is explanatory, seen some "cheat sheets" but they are limited. And within git, there seems to be a menu of commands with brief explanations, but I want a full blown list of ALL commands, and there functions.  I did see that someone else's post about a cheat sheet was closed, but I am not just looking for some cheat sheet.  I am looking for a command and function sheet that will layout ALL Git Commands, and see the programs full functionality.  I don't think this post is a non-productive, or mute topic, but I am a noob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just go through `git help <command>` for each command? Get all git commands via `git help --all`. I have to warn you, there is a crap load of stuff there and I would think it would be overwhelming and not the best way to get your head around all the functionality, but I would admire your desire to do so. (and don't forget about `git help -g` to view the guides as well.)

Comment: Thanks. Probably best to post as a question, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits might be your answer, but haven't tried it and Im only using default OSX 2.7.4.