# Files were not commtting in git, and gives a error message

Tags: git, bash

I am new to git, and stuck while committing a file, and not able to type anything,below is message comes:

---

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:[enter image description here][1]
#       modified:   file_1.txt
```

Comment: it seems you have more a problem of vi than git. you can do commit by typing `git commit -m'your message'`

Comment: I suggest you check this answer out if you don't like using vim. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits

Comment: Set the `EDITOR` environmental variable to whatever editor you are most comfortable with, the you can write your `commit` message there.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is really more of a VIM issue than a Git one.

Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to enter *insert* mode.

Then enter your commit message.  To save your work and exit this screen, type:

<kbd>ESC</kbd>

to leave edit mode, followed by:

<kbd>:wq</kbd>

This should complete the commit and return you to the prompt of your Git bash.  As @olibiaz mentioned, you could also try using:

```
git commit -m 'your commit message here'
```

in which case Git would not bring up the VIM editor.

Comment: You also need to press Escape, to re-enter command mode, before typing `:wq`.

Answer (score 0):

Press `i` for inserting. Once you are done editing the messages, you can press `esc` -> `:wq` -> `enter`  to save and quit.