# How to change the text editor in git to Sublime - currently git commit commands are opening in Notepad

Tags: git, sublimetext3, text-editor

*Despite similar questions that have been posted in the community, I have not seen this specific question addressed.*

I am trying to change the default text editor used by git to Sublime. I am using a Windows machine and downloaded Sublime 3.

Initially, I was running the command `git config --global core.editor "'C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe' -n -w"` in Git Bash, then when I ran a `git commit` it did not open an editor (it just used the Git Bash "editor").

However, when I add the flag `-m` to my git config: `--global core.editor "'C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe' -n -w -m"` and run `Git commit` it now opens up the Notepad editor.

Note I have not changed any of the path or default text editor settings in Windows, I am only trying to have Sublime open up when running git commands.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the output of `git config --list --show-origin | grep -i core.editor` ? This will let us know if your configuration is correct and is not being overridden.

Comment: @AshutoshJindal The output of `git config --list --show-origin | grep -i core.editor` produces this result: 

_file:C:/Users/ryanj/.gitconfig  core.editor='c:/program files/sublime text 3/subl.exe' -w
file:.git/config        core.editor=notepad_

Comment: FYI, the "Git Bash editor" is called Vim.

Comment: Did you read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2596835/1440565)?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes, I read the answer but potentially I'm missing something- is there something specific that you're pointing to?

Comment: Although the original question is about vim, the answer I linked shows how to manually edit .gitconfig to configure sublime text.

Comment: Also, run the command shown in the first comment and edit your question to show the output

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I would prefer to understand what the true issue is (as a learning experience) vs. resorting to manually changing the .gitconfig. I ran the code in the first comment and responded with the results in the second comment.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the requested information instead of posting it add a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

`git config --global core.editor "'c:/program files/sublime text 3/subl.exe' -w"`

This worked for me (i.e. on performing a `git commit` a Sublime Text window opened up where I was able to type the commit message and after saving and closing the window, I checked that this commit had the commit message that I had just typed in with a `git show`) on Windows 10 with Git for Windows version 2.10.2 and Sublime Text 3 build 3126

Note that the windows command line helper `subl.exe` was introduced in Build 3065 on 27 August 2014, so this should work on any build including and after #3065 :

[image]

#### Update: Git config scopes!

The output that OP posted in response to the first comment clearly shows the problem:

Command:

```
git config --list --show-origin | grep -i core.editor

file:C:/Users/ryanj/.gitconfig core.editor='c:/program files/sublime text 3/subl.exe' -w 
file:.git/config core.editor=notepad
```

OP's has a repository level configuration for `core.editor` which is notepad and overrides the global configuration which is set to what he expects (i.e. Sublime Text 3).

To fix this, run the following:

```
git config --unset core.editor
```

and confirm that `git config --list --show-origin | grep -i core.editor` shows you only ONE configuration file (i.e. c:/users/ryanj/.gitconfig) with Sublime Text 3 set as the editor.

Comment: @Ashtosh Jindal I ran the command you listed: `git config --global core.editor "'c:/program files/sublime text 3/subl.exe' -w"`, but when I run `Git commit` it's still opening in Notepad.  Further, when I run `git var GIT_EDITOR` it lists "notepad"

Comment: Have updated my answer, try running `git config --unset core.editor` and re-run `git config --list --show-origin | grep -i core.editor` and post output.

Comment: @Ashtosh Jindal that worked!  Now running `git config --list --show-origin | grep -i core.editor`only produces one line: *$ git config --list --show-origin | grep -i core.editor
file:C:/Users/ryanj/.gitconfig  core.editor='c:/program files/sublime text 3/subl.exe' -w*.  Furthermore, running `git commit` opens Sublime Text.  Thanks!