# Remove git's dependency on Brackets

Tags: git, unix, command-line, adobe-brackets

I had a repeating issue where, whenever I pulled changes from a remote git repository, my terminal would print the following several times and launch Brackets:

```
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
```

I have no idea why it launched Brackets, especially since Sublime Text is my default editor and I never use Brackets anymore. In order to stop that, I uninstalled Brackets. Now when I try to pull I get this message:

```
error: There was a problem with the editor '/Applications/Brackets.app/Contents/MacOS/Brackets -wl1'.
Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.
```

And when I try again:

```
error: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
hint: Please, commit your changes before merging.
fatal: Exiting because of unfinished merge.
```

This happens when I have not made any local changes and git should just pull all new changes without conflict. I know at some point, years ago, I made Brackets my default editor, but soon switched to Sublime Text. Git and Brackets must still be linked somehow but I don't know how to figure it out.

Comment: Does this only happen for a specific local Git repository or all of your repositories?  Do any of the affected repos have any hooks defined?

Comment: Is `GIT_EDITOR` set in your environment?  Does `git config --get-all core.editor` show anything?

Answer (score 1):

If your local repository has any unpublished commits when you pull from the remote, Git will perform a merge of the local and remote HEADs, and a text editor will be opened for you to enter a merge commit message in.  It appears that Git is currently configured to treat Brackets as your preferred text editor; in most cases, this can be changed by editing `core.editor` in your `~/.gitconfig` file (See [How do I make Git use the editor of my choice for commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2596805/744178) for further information).

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for, thanks! Brackets was set up to be my core editor. I just didn't remember setting it.