# Trying to use git commit but i get the wrong output I get this message:

Tags: git, macos

> Kasems-MacBook-Pro:new-git-project mf_a1983$ git commit hint: Waiting
>   for your editor to close the file... '/Applications/Sublime Text
>   .app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl' -n -w: /Applications/Sublime
>   Text .app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl: No such file or directory
>   error: There was a problem with the editor ''/Applications/Sublime
>   Text .app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl' -n -w'. Please supply the
>   message using either -m or -F option.
>   Kasems-MacBook-Pro:new-git-project mf_a1983$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to undo the most recent commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-most-recent-commits-in-git)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2596805/6320293 for some pointers to configure editors

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it clear:

> /Applications/Sublime Text .app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl: No such file or directory error

If you are using version 1 of Sublime Text then the correct path probably is:

```
/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```

(please note there is no space before `.app`.)

If you are using version 2 then the path should be

```
/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```

(the `2` is missing in your configuration.)

To check which it is the correct path, paste any of the above paths into a terminal window, between quotes, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If the path is correct then Sublime Text will start (or bring its window in the foreground, if it is already started.)