# reorder commits with git in rebase

Tags: git

**git log --decorate --oneline --graph --all**

```
* d233053 (HEAD -> crud-phases-tasks) crud phases
* 68a0e7f added some changes
* 45501cb added right menu
* d26549e fixed backend permissions
* f4f52e2 crud tasks and fixed eslint and rubocops errors
*   9fac2e9 (root/dev, dev) Merge branch 'fguerrero/layout' into 'dev'
|\  
| * cc98c21 Improve notifications component
* |   f5eb054 Merge branch 'padame/refactor-request-versions' into 'dev'
|\ \  
| * | 941adc9 H#260 Request list
```

When i run `git rebase -i dev` i'm getting this:

```
pick f4f52e2 crud tasks and fixed eslint and rubocops errors
pick d26549e fixed backend permissions
pick 45501cb added right menu
pick 68a0e7f added some changes
pick d233053 crud phases
```

my last commit is crud phases. I need crud phases like first commit, something like this:

```
reword d233053 crud phases
squash f4f52e2 crud tasks and fixed eslint and rubocops errors
squash d26549e fixed backend permissions
squash 45501cb added right menu
squash 68a0e7f added some changes
```

Comment: And so the question is ...? Did it work changing the rebase specification like that? If not, what happened?

Comment: You just have to reorder the commits and save. If you are not familiar with `vim`, you can still change your default editor:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits

Comment: If you are going to squash the other commits into one, then why re-order? There will be only a single commit at the end and the order of the operations originally performed will be lost.