# How do I get different builds of vim to ignore parts of the ~/vimrc that they do not the the plugins for?

Tags: vim, vi

My centos 7 has two vim binaries:
/usr/bin/vi
/usr/bin/vim

When launching either of them they bring up:

> VIM - Vi IMproved
>   version 7.4.1099

From searching around online I believe that these two versions are vim and vim-minimal. The problem is that vi and vim-minimal interpert the ~/.vimrc differently. When opening vim its great. When opening vim-minimal I get lots of errors. Below is a representation of my ~/.vimrc file:

```
set number
set nowrap
set modeline
set clipboard=unnamedplus  "Enables mouse center clip pasting, while holding shift, in insert mode.

"Below sets up the mouse in such a way that allows vi split screen resizing while in tmux and screen.
set mouse+=a
if &term =~ '^screen'
    " tmux knows the extended mouse mode
    set ttymouse=xterm2
endif

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
""" User Defined Functions
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
"Opens up sage specific work in new tabs
fu! Setup1()
  :bd!|e /home/me/example1.h | vsplit /home/me/example1.cc
  :tabnew /home/me/example2.h | vsplit /home/me/example2.cc
  :tabnew /home/me/example3.h | vsplit /home/me/example3.cc
  :tabnew /home/me/example4.h | vsplit /home/me/example4.cc
  :tabnew /home/me/example5.h | vsplit /home/me/example5.cc
  :tabnew /home/me/example6.h | vsplit /home/me/example6.cc
endfunction

"Opens up the most edited rc files in new tabs
fu! RCS()
  :bd!|e ~/.cshrc
  :tabnew ~/.vimrc
  :tabnew ~/.tmux.conf
endfunction
```

The problem is my user defined functions. When /usr/bin/vi is opened it opens all of the documents in my two functions in new tabs. A resonable workaround would be to not use /usr/bin/vi but it is what git opens.

Ideally I would be able to have an if statement that checks what binary is running this rc file. Is that possible?

Comment: Why is git tagged?

Comment: @evolutionxbox the real issue the OP is having is that git is using `vi` instead of `vim`

Comment: @ChristianGibbons there's gotta be a dupe target for this then?

Comment: https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/gracefully-degrading-vimrc/

Comment: max630 you found it! This is it. You should have posted this as an answer so I can give you the little green check. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make Git use the editor of my choice for commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits)

Comment: Not a duplicate of that. The question is about getting different builds of vim to see different parts of the ~/.vimrc file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following blog post discusses how to degrade vimrc for different builds of vim that may have different packages and different capabilities (and thus react to vimrc differently):

[gracefully degrading .vimrc](https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/gracefully-degrading-vimrc/)

(answer provided by max630 in the comments to my question)

Answer (score 2):

You can configure git to use the editor of your choice.  You can set the environment variable `GIT_EDITOR` or you can set a configuration file with `git config --global core.editor /usr/bin/vim` to set the `core.editor` variable.

If neither of those is set, it may fall back to the `VISUAL` environment variable.  On that note, you will likely want to set that in your `~/.bashrc` as a more system-wide solution so other utilities that may want to open an editor default to `/usr/bin/vim` over `/usr/bin/vi`

Comment: Thank you. I have changed my global config variable to /usr/bin/vim; and it worked. (sadly I can't up vote you)

Comment: @Colonel, there should be a grey check mark underneath the upvote buttons; you should do that instead =)