# Prevent Git Interactive Rebase from opening Atom

Tags: git, atom-editor, rebase

I am currently trying to squash my last commit using interactive rebase. However, when I type `git rebase -i HEAD^`, Atom is opened.

Since I want to do this from Vim, how do I prevent Atom from opening so that I can do rebase from the terminal window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pleas try `git config --global core.editor "vim"`
This will set Vim as your git default editor

you can see more detail here [How do I make Git use the editor of my choice for commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits)

Comment: In addition: if you only want to change it for rebase you can use `git config --global sequence.editor "vim"`