# How to fix the git commit

Tags: git, macos, terminal

A few days ago I tried to configure Sublime Text 3 so that it would open when I did commit in git, but an error always comes out, and when I try to put back the vim I get this:

```
MacBook-Air-de-Andres:bin andr3yvlz$ git config --global core.editor vim
warning: core.editor has multiple values
error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value
       Use a regexp, --add or --replace-all to change core.editor.
```

i try to do this too:

```
MacBook-Air-de-Andres:bin andr3yvlz$ git config --replace-all core.editor vim
fatal: not in a git directory
MacBook-Air-de-Andres:bin andr3yvlz$
```

The commit error is:

```
MacBook-Air-de-Andres:Andr3yvlz andr3yvlz$ git add .
MacBook-Air-de-Andres:Andr3yvlz andr3yvlz$ git commit
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... subl -n -w: subl: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'subl -n -w'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
MacBook-Air-de-Andres:Andr3yvlz andr3yvlz$
```

if someone knows how to configure the sublime with git, it would be very helpful, and thanks in advance

Comment: You can change it with `git config --global --replace-all` (supply two options together).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make Git use the editor of my choice for commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits)

Comment: I'd recommend opening up your user profile's `.gitconfig` file to see where you have the duplicates of `core.editor` and possibly make adjustments there (though it's recommended to make changes with the git commands). You should be able to find it here on a Mac: `~/.gitconfig`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to remove the option `code.editor` from `~/.gitconfig` and than add it.

```
$ git config --global --unset-all core.editor
$ git config --global core.editor "vim"
```