# Git commit hook for when editor closed

Tags: git, commit, githooks

I have implemented a commit hook to check the commit message and abort the commit if the message isn't formatted correctly. I've done this with the `commit-msg` hook.

However, this will only work if you commit with the `-m` flag. If you omit that flag (because you want to use your editor to add the message), then the commit hook will fail (no message).

From what I have read, both the `pre-commit` and `commit-msg` hook are fired before the editor is opened. Is there a way to do something similar that waits for the editor to be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the `commit-msg` hook is fired once the message is ready (so, after the user closes the editor), this hook is getting a path to a file with the message value.

From the docs:

> The commit-msg hook takes one parameter, which again is the path to a temporary file that contains the commit message written by the developer.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it's an issue with the editor. Using vim works fine but using something like VSCode doesn't. Maybe because the terminal loses focus or something

Comment: Maybe this answer will solve it (--wait):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2596835/4039952