# How do I save git commit message under Powershell and nano ? (Ctrl+O doesn't work)

Tags: windows, git, powershell

I'm on Windows. After git commit, I entered a message.
Then I tried Ctrl+O to save but it doesn't work (I guess I'm on nano, am I mistaken?).
[image]

Comment: Re "I guess I'm on nano": please tell _us_ what editor `git` is using on your system; what does `git config core.editor` return?

Comment: It looks like `vim`. Try `Esc`, and then input `:wq`, and `Enter`. To set an editor as the default, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits.

Comment: @ElpieKay, see also: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/one-out-of-every-20-000-stack-overflow-visitors-is-just-trying-to-exit-vim-5a6b6175e7b6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nano was [added as a choice in 2017](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/pull/161) with [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), because of [issue 1224](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1224): "Add nano as a choice of editor(s) for git-commit because vim increases what we have to tell to beginners" (!)

But the editor by default remains "vim".

In your case, since you have modified the comment, `ESC` followed by `:x` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

If this is nano, commands are `Ctrl` + `X` , then `Enter` (maybe multiple times depending on your conf)