# VSCode remote shh hangs on "git rebase --continue"

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote-ssh

I have a problem with rebasing when works on the remote pc using remote-shh extension. When I finish rebasing and commit it git hangs up with the issue: "Waiting for your editor to close the file...". I configured git on my remote pc as git config --system core.editor "code --wait" and when I finish rebasing git opens editor on the remote pc, not on vscode I am using. Is there any way to fix this behaviour?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make git use the editor of my choice for commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits) Configure it to use vim or pico so that the editing interface appears direct in the terminal you're using for SSH.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not using terminal directly. I use gui provided by the VSCode remote-ssh extension.

Comment: I've never done that, but I still think my idea might work. :)

Comment: In the VSCode integrated terminal, type `type code`. If it does not point to something inside `~/.vscode-server`, then something is not working right with your setup. I would guess something in your shell startup files puts the system `code` before the `code` from `~/.vscode-server` in your `PATH`...

Comment: Yes, it is doesnt point to ~/.vscode-server. I have no idea how to solve it, because vscode-server is installed when the connection to the remote pc happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSCode 1.70 (local and remote SSH, July 2022) should improve the situation.

It includes "[Polish and fix git rebase --continue experience](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/114461)", fixed by [PR 151824](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/151824), and released to [VSCode insider today](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

[image: rebase --continue]