# How to configure nvim as git editor?

Tags: git, neovim

I'm having an issue with `nvim` as my git editor. I've specified `nvim` as the global `core.editor`, but I need to yank something everytime I'm making a commit. How should I properly specify `nvim` as the default commit message editor?

Basically, my workflow currently is to run

```
$ git commit
yy
```

Error I'm getting if not yanking anything:

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... error: There was a problem with the editor '/usr/bin/nvim'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

I write and close the commit message with `:wq`, if that has anything of use.

`nvim` version:

```
$ nvim --version
NVIM v0.9.5
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.1702233742

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info
```

`git` version:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.44.0
```

Terminal:

```
rxvt-unicode (urxvt) v9.31 - released: 2023-01-02
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately `nvim` doesn't have such flag.

Comment: Apparently running setting the core.editor is unnecessary, I just need to run `git commit` again.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You think I should remove my previous comments?

Comment: Your config should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73512457/112968

Comment: Looking at the answer below... I shouldn't have deleted my comment :-D

Comment: Yes, it seems like `-f` exists, but it isn't mentioned in the manual `man nvim`.

Comment: In original Vim, you would do `:help -f` to see the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can sometimes occur due to the way Neovim interacts with the terminal.

One workaround is to configure Neovim to run in a way that signals Git when the editing is complete. You can do this by setting the wait flag in the core.editor configuration. Here's how you can do it:

```
git config --global core.editor "nvim -f"
```

The -f flag tells Neovim to run in a "foreground" mode, which makes it wait until the file is closed before returning control to the terminal. This should allow Git to detect when the commit message editing is complete.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it didn't seem to fix the issue. Getting the same error message.

Also the `-f` doesn't seem to be documented in `man nvim`. Where's this documented?