# Git is using Vim for Commit messages

Tags: git, vim, commit

I have just started using git and when I git commit it uses the VIM text editor to change write the commit message. Is this normal?

In the tutorials and examples I have read, nowhere has VIM been used.

Is it because I'm using windows 7 ***64 bit*** edition?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set up an editor to work with Git on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows)

Comment: I do agree that the default use of VIM on windows (not only 64 bit) is disturbing. If you never used it before it is a real pain to only find out how to quit. Default should be as simple as possible.

Comment: ...and [Here](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/vimcheat.html)'s how to quit (and not only) VIM if you are a VIM n00b like myself

Answer (score 10):

If you did not set an editor via the [`$GIT_EDITOR` environment variable, `core.editor` configuration variable, the `$VISUAL` or `$EDITOR` environment variables](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-var.html), it will use `vi`.

Answer (score 0):

[How can I set up an editor to work with Git on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows)

Comment: should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Please try to add the relevant bits of text into your answer and use the link as a supporting reference.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal and it has nothing to do with the flavour of windows that you are using.