# How can I use gvim for svn commit messages under Windows?

Tags: windows, svn, vim

Under *nix I can set `SVN_EDITOR` to `gvim --nofork` to do the trick, but that doesn't seem to work under Windows. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?  What exactly did you do, what happened and what did you expect to happen?  Your question is a little vague...

Comment: If I set `SVN_EDITOR` to `gvim --nofork` and then do `svn ci`, svn doesn't wait for gvim to quit but instead issues this error message and exits: `svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: system('"gvim --nofork" svn-commit.tmp') returned 1`. Similarly if I set `SVN_EDITOR` to just `gvim`. The problem is now solved thanks to zundr. Thanks everyone for your attention.

Comment: I suspected that was what you meant, I just wasn't completely sure.  Either a batch file or adjusting `guioptions` in `vimrc` should work in that case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have installed the batch files (c:\windows\gvim.bat), just set `EDITOR` to `gvim -f`, the batch file processes the -f argument and sets the no-fork option.

The trick in the batch file is running `START /WAIT path\to\gvim.exe %*` (see the **/WAIT** argument).

If you don't have the batch files, just create a new one with the command above, and set `EDITOR` to the newly create batch file.

Comment: Yes, I do have batch files installed and so following your advice I've set `SVN_EDITOR` to `gvim -f` and it worked like a charm. Thanks very much for your suggestion and explanation!

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows/1574521#1574521) was written for Git, but should directly apply.

To make this work, try the following.

1. Create a one-line batch file (named `svn_editor.bat`) which contains the following:
2. `"path/to/gvim.exe" --nofork "%*"`
3. Place `svn_editor.bat` on your `PATH`.
4. Set `SVN_EDITOR=svn_editor.bat`

With this done, SVN should correctly invoke the gvim executable.

NOTE 1: The --nofork option to gvim insures that it blocks until the commit message has been written.

NOTE 2: The quotes around the path to gvim is required if you have spaces in the path.

NOTE 3: The quotes around "%*" are needed just in case git passes a file path with spaces.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggested approach and it works well. I think I'm going to use zundr's approach however as it's easier to setup and easier to memorize. But thanks anyway, +1 from me ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is passing parameters to prevent forking to gvim (your question was a little vague), then you can either create a batch file that calls gvim with the required parameters or you could simply add the following to your `vimrc` (NOT `gvimrc`) and point `SVN_EDITOR` at `gvim.exe`:

```
set guioptions+=f
```

This tells vim not to fork when creating the GUI and has the advantage of not having to mess around with batch files.  For more information, see:

```
:help gui-fork
```

Comment: I'm sorry you found my question vague. I was asking how to teach svn to use gvim when `svn commit` is invoked without `-m` argument, and in a way that will work with no issues.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether you meant that svn wasn't looking at SVN_EDITOR, whether the path to gvim was wrong, whether the file provided was wrong (e.g. a space issue as fixed by Tim Henigan) or whether it was a forking issue (as fixed by Tim Henigan's, zundr's and my answers).