# Vim for Windows - What do I type to save and exit from a file?

Tags: git, vim, windows-xp, git-commit

Using Windows XP I accidentally typed `git commit -a` instead of `git commit -am "My commit message"`, and now I'm viewing my CMD prompt filled with the file version of my commit message ("Please enter the commit message for your..."). I've added my message to the top, but now I can't figure out how to save and leave. I tried to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>, but it doesn't do anything, but add `^` where the cursor is.

I also tried <kbd>Esc</kbd> first, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>, but it says `No write since last change (add ! to override)`.

Comment: Oh, it's such a relief that I'm not the only one that got stuck at that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How to exit the Vim editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-to-exit-the-vim-editor)*

Answer (score 555, accepted):

Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to make sure you are out of the edit mode and then type:

```
:wq
```

Comment: @User789 for anything specific or in general?
If you're looking for generic commands try this website: http://www.viemu.com/a_vi_vim_graphical_cheat_sheet_tutorial.html

Comment: They really could have added this as a comment so thousands of us weren't sent out of the terminal for three characters!! But I think nunopolonia is glad they didn't =)

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have ***multiple keyboard layouts*** and you forget you are ***not on english keyboard layout***, you might get stuck and thinking this doesn't work. Hope I helped someone not waste time like I did.

Comment: Thank god I found this. Seriously, it wouldn't have hurt to just add that one piece of direction to the enter commit message screen??

Answer (score 54):

Instead of telling you how you could execute a certain command (<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>), I can provide you two links that may help you with VIM:

- http://bullium.com/support/vim.html provides an HTML quick reference card
- http://tnerual.eriogerg.free.fr/vim.html provides a PDF quick reference card in several languages, optimized for print-out, fold and put on your desk drawer

However, the best way to learn Vim is not only using it for Git commits, but as a regular editor for your everyday work.

If you're not going to switch to Vim, it's nonsense to keep its commands in mind. In that case, go and [set up your favourite editor to use with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows).

Comment: +1 for this really helpfull answer. I prefer Emacs and thanks to your link I don't have to google for a solution.

Comment: +1 for the explanation on VIM and how to set up my own editor

Comment: Teaching how to fish is better than giving him a fish to eat. Thanks.

Comment: Best way to answer the question that should have been asked. Thx

Comment: HTML link is broken.

Answer (score 36):

<kbd>Esc</kbd> to make sure you exit insert mode, then `:wq` (colon w q) or `ZZ` (shift-Z shift-Z).

Comment: Anyone else noticed how much easier this `Shift-Z` `Shift-Z` is than the other one? And by the way, does anything ever get less intuitive? Oh yes, I'm a citizen of Windows!

Answer (score 32):

- Press `i` or `a` to get into insert mode, and type the message of choice
- Press `ESC` several times to get out of insert mode, or any other mode you might have run into by accident

  - to save, `:wq`, `:x` or `ZZ`
  - to exit without saving, `:q!` or `ZQ`

To reload a file and undo all changes you have made...:

Press several times `ESC` and then enter `:e!`.

Answer (score 12):

A faster way to

- Save
- and quit

would be

```
:x
```

If you have opened multiple files you may need to do a

```
:xa
```

Comment: Note that :x will only write files that have changed.

Answer (score 5):

`:q!`  will force an unconditional no-save exit

Comment: This should be a comment. It's highly relevant but does not answer the question. On contrary it talks about a command that does the opposite of what is asked for. Relevant but not an answer

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
:wq!
```

The exclamation mark is used for overriding read-only mode.